# Cross-section of graph

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to use the following code to plot the cross-section of the graph z=x^2+y^2 and x=t. I use Manipulate to vary t.

```
h = z - x^2 - y^2;
g = x;
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == t}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10,
     200}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, g - h]}, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{t}}, 
   ContourStyle -> 
    Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]], 
   SphericalRegion -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   ViewPoint -> {1.7, 1, 0.5}], 
  Graphics3D[{Text["x", Scaled[{1.1, .5, 0}], {0, -1}], 
    Text["y", Scaled[{.5, 1.1, 0}], {0, -1}], 
    Text["z", Scaled[{.5, .5, 1.1}]]}], Boxed -> False], {{t, 0}, -5, 
  5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, Dynamic[Row[{"Cross-Section z = x^2+y^2 and x=", t}]]}}]
```

But the graph I got looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why there is this zig-zag blue line?

Comment: There is mesh on both surfaces now, the one on a plane is smooth.

Comment: @Kuba, I am sorry. Can you elaborate? I must admit that I am new to Mathematica.

Comment: Split ContourPlot into two ContourPlots, and add mesh only to the one where `z ==0`.

Comment: Also, drop mesh and use boundary style, like in: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5968/5478 does it fit your needs?

Comment: @Kuba, splitting ContourPlot did the trick.