# Is it possible to plot any implicit equation without knowing its x and y limits?

Tags: plotting

I have an equation: 9 x^2 + 11 y^2 == 68 + 2 Sqrt[3] x y. Can I plot this function in mathematica without giving the {x, , } and {y, , }??

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha has some good heuristics for this sort of thing, so one might do `WolframAlpha["plot 9 x^2+11 y^2\[Equal]68+2 Sqrt[3] x y"]` for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RegionPlot[
 ImplicitRegion[9 x^2 + 11 y^2 == 68 + 2 Sqrt[3] x y, {x, y}]]
```

[image]

For non-trivial examples, [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) with explicit bounds can be *much* faster.

You can also find the bounds with functions like [`MaxValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue.html), e.g.

```
MaxValue[{x, 9 x^2 + 11 y^2 == 68 + 2 Sqrt[3] x y}, {x, y}]
(* Sqrt[187/6]/2 *)
```