# Intersection lines of surfaces from list contour plots

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry

I have two plots made with `ListContourPlot3D`. Is there a way to find the intersection curves of the surfaces represented in the two plots?

I have tried `ListInterpolation` and then `FindRoot`, but got many error messages. Before trying to fix those errors, I wanted to check if perhaps there is an easier way to do this.

Below is an example of how to generate data similar to what I have. Please note that I do not have analytic functions themselves, only their values.

```
table1 = Table[
   2*Log[x]*x^3 + 4*y + z - 25, {x, 0.1, 10, 0.1}, {y, 0.1, 10, 
    0.1}, {z, 0.1, 10, 0.1}];

table2 = Table[
   2*Log[1/x]*y^3 + 4*y + z + 75, {x, 0.1, 10, 0.1}, {y, 0.1, 10, 
    0.1}, {z, 0.1, 10, 0.1}];

plot1 = ListContourPlot3D[table1, Contours -> {0}, 
   DataRange -> {{0.1, 10}, {0.1, 10}, {0.1, 10}}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.4],
    Mesh -> None];

plot2 = ListContourPlot3D[table2, Contours -> {0}, 
   DataRange -> {{0.1, 10}, {0.1, 10}, {0.1, 10}}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.4],
    Mesh -> None];

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Comment: You should post some example data for people to play with, but I suspect a solution would be similar to what was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968).

Comment: See [this help page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for advice on improving your question.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I have added an example of how to generate data similar to what I have and would be grateful if you could take a look at this once again. Please note that this is just an example and that I do not have analytic functions themselves, only their values. Following your advice, I managed to extract the surfaces but could not visualize their intersection.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason that I cannot understand, `ListContourPlot3D` perturbes the dimensions in a weird way. I prefer to use `ListInterpolation` in conjunction with `ContourPlot3D`. In this way, one can employ `ImplicitRegion` and `DiscretizeRegion` on the interpolating function generated by `ListInterpolation` in order to determine the intersection.
This may take a bit longer that `ListContourPlot3D` but it results also in smoother surfaces.

```
g1 = ListInterpolation[table1, {{0.1, 10}, {0.1, 10}, {0.1, 10}}];
g2 = ListInterpolation[table2, {{0.1, 10}, {0.1, 10}, {0.1, 10}}];

plot1 = ContourPlot3D[
   g1[x, y, z], {x, 0.1, 10.}, {y, 0.1, 10.}, {z, 0.1, 10.}, 
   Contours -> {0}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> ColorData[97][1], 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"];
plot2 = ContourPlot3D[
   g2[x, y, z], {x, 0.1, 10.}, {y, 0.1, 10.}, {z, 0.1, 10.}, 
   Contours -> {0}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> ColorData[97][2], 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"];

R = ImplicitRegion[
   g1[x, y, z] == 0 && g2[x, y, z] == 0, {{x, 0.1, 10}, {y, 0.1, 10}, {z, 0.1, 10}}
   ];
S = DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.025];
plot3 = Graphics3D[{Thick, 
    GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[S], 
     MeshCells[S, 1, "Multicells" -> True]]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Show[plot1, plot2, plot3]
```

[image]

Comment: I did not manage to compute the intersection of the surfaces with `RegionIntersection`. Apparently, `RegionIntersection` works only for full-dimensional regions. Very sad.

Comment: You can get the desired coordinate system with `Transpose[table1, {3, 2, 1}]`. I think this difference comes from the image coordinate system v.s. the standard Cartesian coordinate system. I wonder if it makes sense to have a builtin `DataReversed` analog for 3D. Here's some info: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VolumeRenderingAndProcessing.html#1900524579

Answer (score 3):

Using Henrik's `g1` and `g2` in a single `ContourPlot3D` with the option `BoundaryStyle` (as in the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968) mentioned by J.M. in comments):

```
ContourPlot3D[{g1[x, y, z] == 0, g2[x, y, z] == 0}, 
   {x, 0.1, 5.}, {y, 0.1, 10.}, {z, 0.1, 5.}, 
   Mesh -> None, BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.4], 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue, Yellow}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Opacity[1, Red]}] /. 
 Line[x_] :> Tube[x, .1]
```

[image]

Note: this is very slow.