# Drawing Curve, Interpolating Points on a Sphere

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I am implementing Lagrange motion of degree 6 in Wolfram Matematica,
I have implemented everything and now when i came to an 'easy part', drawing part i am stuck.

Which function could i use to draw on the same graph sphere interpolating point and a curve? Also could you please give an example of a sphere of some radius centered at 0, with some curve and points on it? I will be very thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to mathematica.se. I gave you an example for your specific question, but please simply search the site. You will find great resources like the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5972/187).

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you an example but please also check the many posts we have on this site. Generally, you can combine all kinds of graphics with Mathematica. So for instance, plotting a parametric curve and a sphere in the same plot can be done with

```
curve[t_] := {
   Cos[t]*Sin[2*ArcTan[Exp[-t/8]]],
   Sin[t]*Sin[2*ArcTan[Exp[-t/8]]],
   Cos[2*ArcTan[Exp[t/8]]]
   };

Show[
 Graphics3D[Sphere[]],
 ParametricPlot3D[curve[t], {t, -20, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image]