# How to plot a 3D-subspace of a $\mathbb{C}^2$ curve?

Tags: plotting, complex

I am trying to visualize the intersection of a complex curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$ with various 3D subspaces but I am not sure how to get Mathematica to do it (so far I have been able to visualize intersections with 2D subspaces using ReIm and ContourPlot). For example, say I have the curve $p^4+qp^2+1=q^8$ in $\mathbb{C^2}$, how would I get Mathematica to plot all values where $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $q \in \mathbb{C}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show an example anywhere from the web or a paper?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

Using the method in  [Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves/5972#5972)

```
Block[{F},
 F[p_, q_] := p^4 + q*p^2 - q^8 + 1;
 ContourPlot3D[
  ComplexExpand@ReIm@F[pR + I*pI, qR + I*qI] /. pI -> 0 // Evaluate,
  {pR, -4, 4}, {qR, -4, 4}, {qI, -2, 2},
  MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 25,
  Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0], Mesh -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 
    2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {{Green, Tube[.03]}}}, Boxed -> False]
 ]
```

[image]