# Slice through Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

is there any possibility to slice through a Graphics3D object? At the end I would like to have a stack of images slicing , e.g. $n$ times in $z$-direction: $((x,y,z_{0}), (x,y,z_{1}),…,(x,y,z_{n}))$

Here is an example of random spheres, which I would like to slice.

```
z = 100;
p = RandomReal[100, {z, 3}];
r = RandomReal[10, {z}];
obj = GraphicsComplex[p, Sphere[Range[z], r]];
t0 = AbsoluteTime[];
gr = Graphics3D[obj, Axes -> True]
```

I would be pleased about any suggestions.

Comment: You can use `PlotRange` to emulate that to a certain degree, try: `Manipulate[
 gr = Graphics3D[obj, Axes -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, z}}], {{z, 100}, 0, 100}]`. For the image stack, this will be more complicated...

Comment: If you only want circle sections, this could be solved in an analytic fashion. Intersections on general graphics objects are not implemented yet (9.01).

Comment: It seems that @YvesKlett is right so maybe you can confirm that your objects are only `Sphere`s or provide a minimal example of the data you are working with so we can help with your case.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25511/does-it-make-sense-to-ask-for-the-color-of-a-graphics3d-voxel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by specifying a dynamic `PlotRange`. Here is an example using `Manipulate`. You will need to adapt your range for each dimension:

```
z = 100;
p = RandomReal[100, {z, 3}];
r = RandomReal[10, {z}];
obj = GraphicsComplex[p, Sphere[Range[z], r]];
t0 = AbsoluteTime[];
gr = Graphics3D[obj, Axes -> True]

Manipulate[
 Show[gr, PlotRange -> {{x, Automatic}, {y, Automatic}, {z, 
     Automatic}}], {x, 0, 100, 1}, {y, 0, 100, 1}, {z, 0, 100, 1}]
```

[image]

In order to generate images you will have to replace the `Manipulate` by a `Table` command and generate the images. Have a closer look at `ViewPoint` to specify the view on your `Graphics3D` object. This will allow you to generate images looking from the different directions.

Here is an example:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[gr, ViewPoint -> {0, -Infinity, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {{x, Automatic}, {y, Automatic}, {z, Automatic}}], {x, 
  0, 100, 1}, {y, 0, 100, 1}, {z, 0, 100, 1}]
```

[image]

**edit**

To get sections you could also use `PlotRange`. Here is an example giving you slices of thickness 1 in y-direction:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[gr, ViewPoint -> {0, -Infinity, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {{x, Automatic}, {y, y + 1}, {z, Automatic}}], {x, 0, 
  100, 1}, {y, 0, 100, 1}, {z, 0, 100, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the analytical expressions for your surfaces (as it's the case for the spheres) there are  lot of ways to do that by using any *3D[] plotting function like this:

```
Image3D@Table[ImageTake[
              Image@Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
                          PlotRange -> {-1, s}, ClippingStyle -> {Transparent, Green}, 
                          Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Transparent, 
                          Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -Infinity}], 
             10 {1, -1}, 10 {1, -1}], 
         {s, -.9, .7, .1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: yuck... why green? Image search returns [this](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/717kAmgHICL._SL1500_.jpg) :-)

Comment: @YvesKlett Green, as most things in the history of mathematics is just because _I like it_ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematical_notation :)