# Generating 2D models from a 3D model

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a model of cube with randomly distributed spheres included there.

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[.3], Cuboid[White, {0, 0, 0}, {0.01, 0.01, 0.01}]}, 
  Table[{Black, Sphere[RandomReal[{.000175, 0.01 - .000175}, 3], 0.000175]}, {j, 1, 250}]}]
```

My problem is to extract models of each layer. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Your code does not evaluate without error as currently posted. Did you intend `{Opacity[.3], White, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {0.01, 0.01, 0.01}]}`?

Comment: So with your model, you have the center positions and radii of all the spheres so you could get an analytic form for any 2D slice.  Is that what you want, or are you looking for a more general way to get 2D slices of more complicated 3D objects?  If so, I think your answer is here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32991/slice-through-graphics3d