# About Slicing through Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

Recently I have seen a code in mathematica about Slicing through Graphics3D in [Slice through Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32991/slice-through-graphics3d). My questions is: Is it possible to fill out these spheres? I have problem with generating randomly distributed filled spheres inside cube.
Bakha

Comment: `gr = Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Yellow, Black], obj}, Axes -> True]` kind of gives this effect since you can't perceive depth with black inside.

Comment: In my project I have to generate 3D model of randomly distributed filled spheres inside cube. As a result I have to show the distribution of the spheres in the cube layer by layer. Using the mentioned before Slice through Graphics3D problem I have a 3D model but when I am going to see it layer by layer I am seeing just square with empty region inside. Is it possible to fill it out

Comment: I understand your question and I maintain that my suggestion [kind of gives the expected result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QgeHR.png). It's not the real deal, hence I posted it as a comment.

Comment: Is it possible to see it layer by layer separately? I mean to see first layer in first graph, second in second graph, etc., without adding one layer to others.

Comment: Dear @Bakha you have two profiles registered, it seems: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/20101/bakha) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19856/bakha). Please follow the instructions at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts so your total reputation counts.

Answer (score 6):

With **V10** you can use `ClipPlanes`

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.5], Cuboid[]},
 Axes -> True,
 ClipPlanes -> {{1, 1, -1, 0}},
 ClipPlanesStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.2], Green]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}],
 ClipPlanes -> {{-1, 1, 0, 1}},
 ClipPlanesStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[.3], Brown]}]
```

[image]

Something like this?

```
z = 100;
p = RandomReal[100, {z, 3}];
r = RandomReal[10, {z}];
spheres = GraphicsComplex[p, Sphere[Range[z], r]];

Grid[
 Partition[
  Map[
   Graphics3D[{Red, spheres},
     Axes -> True,
     ClipPlanes -> {{0, 1, 0, #}},
     ClipPlanesStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.2], Green]}] &,
   Range[-1, -100, -10]],
  5],
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: In my project I have to generate 3D model of randomly distributed filled spheres inside cube. As a result I have to show the distribution of the spheres in the cube layer by layer. Using the mentioned before Slice through Graphics3D problem I have a 3D model but when I am going to see it layer by layer I am seeing just square with empty region inside. Is it possible to fill it out?