# 2d dxf output of a 3d model

Tags: mesh

Hi I have imported a 3d model into Mathematica converting it from a PLY or STL format. This works fine. By using the procedure in [Slice through Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32991/slice-through-graphics3d)
and modifying it slightly for a mesh region rather than a Graphics3D image I can get nice 2D elevations, planes and sections. The problem comes when I want to export those views in 2D via dxf into a cad program. It only seems to export the whole 3d model not just the 2d view. Any guidance as to how to get just the 2d view into a dxf format?

Here is a simple example. I first draw a tetrahedron

```
t = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 
2}}, {Tetrahedron[{1, 2, 3, 5}]}]
```

I then take a view of it. In this case the base

```
base = MeshRegion[t, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -Infinity}]
```

I then export it as a dxf and reimport it.

```
Export["base.dxf", base]
Import["base.dxf"]
```

This gives me the whole model i.e. a 3d dxf file rather than just the 2d view which is what I want.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example?  Exporting a 2D mesh region as a DWF file seems to work, `disk = DiscretizeGraphics@Disk[];
Export["disk.dxf", disk]` gives no errors, and I'm able to reimport the resulting file just fine.

Comment: The problem is that you aren't really making any changes to the `MeshRegion` when you specify a `ViewPoint`.  After evaluateing the line `base = .....`, try using your mouse to manipulate the result and you'll find it is still a 3D object, not 2D.  Also, evaluate `RegionEmbeddingDimension@base`

Comment: I understand but how do I get an exportable 2D slice or view from a 3D model? Is there an equivalent to Image3Dslices for Mesh Regions?