# Creating 3D dice

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing

How to create an image of a 3D die from the 2D images?

[image][image][image]

[image][image]
[image]

There is an example in the [Documentation Center](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html)

[image]

I tried 
[image]

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34896/193

Comment: You can find all you need in the documentation for [Texture](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html)

Comment: Related: [63677](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63677/731)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By using a cube with rounded corners, from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49347/731), and by applying the images as "stickers" onto the sides of this cube, the dice can be made to look a little bit more realistic. The black border does not translate well to a 3D visualization, so I hid it by fiddling with the vertex coordinates.

```
faces = Import /@ {
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdfMj.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7w6.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/WayOQ.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgjkA.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa5bK.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8szh.png"
    };

polygons = With[{eps = 0.01, k = 0.05}, {
    {{k, k, 0 - eps}, {k, 1 - k, 0 - eps}, {1 - k, 1 - k, 0 - eps}, {1 - k, k, 0 - eps}},
    {{k, 0 - eps, k}, {1 - k, 0 - eps, k}, {1 - k, 0 - eps, 1 - k}, {k, 0 - eps, 1 - k}},
    {{1 + eps, k, k}, {1 + eps, 1 - k, k}, {1 + eps, 1 - k, 1 - k}, {1 + eps, k, 1 - k}},
    {{1 - k, 1 + eps, k}, {k, 1 + eps, k}, {k, 1 + eps, 1}, {1 - k, 1 + eps, 1 - k}},
    {{0 - eps, 1 - k, k}, {0 - eps, k, k}, {0 - eps, k, 1 - k}, {0 - eps, 1 - k, 1 - k}},
    {{1 - k, k, 1 + eps}, {1 - k, 1 - k, 1 + eps}, {k, 1 - k, 1 + eps}, {k, k, 1 + eps}}
    }];

(* roundedCuboid: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49313/drawing-a-cuboid-with-rounded-corners *)
roundedCuboid[p0 : {x0_, y0_, z0_}, p1 : {x1_, y1_, z1_}, r_] := {
   EdgeForm[None],
   Cuboid[p0 + {0, r, r}, p1 - {0, r, r}],
   Cuboid[p0 + {r, 0, r}, p1 - {r, 0, r}],
   Cuboid[p0 + {r, r, 0}, p1 - {r, r, 0}],
   Table[Cylinder[{{x0 + r, y, z}, {x1 - r, y, z}}, r], {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}], 
   Table[Cylinder[{{x, y0 + r, z}, {x, y1 - r, z}}, r], {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}], 
   Table[Cylinder[{{x, y, z0 + r}, {x, y, z1 - r}}, r], {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}], 
   Table[Sphere[{x, y, z}, r], {x, {x0 + r, x1 - r}}, {y, {y0 + r, y1 - r}}, {z, {z0 + r, z1 - r}}]
   };

sticker[img_, coords_] := With[{eps = 0.92}, {
   EdgeForm[None],
   Texture[img],
   Polygon[coords, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{eps, eps}, {1 - eps, eps}, {1 - eps, 1 - eps}, {eps, 1 - eps}}]
   }]

Graphics3D[{
  White, roundedCuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, 1/20],
  MapThread[sticker, {faces, polygons}]
  },
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I wonder if it might be neater (and less error prone) to extract the geometry from `PolyhedronData["Cube", ...]` and modify it for the rounded edges. (e.g. turn the `Line`s in `"Edges"` into `Tube`s, and then offset all the faces along their normal).

Comment: @Martin, more or less what I did in my answer to that other thread, but I went further and used NURBS for rounding out the edges and corners.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Maybe. Does not really matter since I am using a pre-made working solution for that part but then why did I prefer that answer over the others? I actually like being able to see exactly what's going on by just looking at the code. Hiding the construction of the box in a higher level  built-in function prevents that.

Answer (score 23):

`Image3D` isn't what you're looking for. That actually generates a "3-dimensional image" with voxels instead of pixels (by using the given images as layers in the voxel grid). That's what you're seeing in the example you included.

What you want is render a bunch of (square) polygons and use your images as **textures**. To do so you'll need `Texture` and the `VertexTextureCoordinates` option of `Polygons`. You can get the faces of a cube from `PolyhedronData`, which you can destructure and then reassemble with the correct textures. (I wonder if there's a way to apply multiple textures to the single `GraphicsComplex` object returned by `PolyhedronData` instead.)

Here is some code:

```
faces = Import /@ {
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdfMj.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7w6.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/WayOQ.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgjkA.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa5bK.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8szh.png"
};

(* standard texture coordinates for mapping a texture completely onto a quad *)
fullQuad = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};

(* get the cube's face polygons *)
cube = PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces"];

(* pick out the individual faces and pair them with the corresponding texture *)
Graphics3D[
 MapThread[
  {
    Texture[#],
    Polygon[cube[[1, #2]], VertexTextureCoordinates -> fullQuad]
    } &,
  {
   faces,
   cube[[2, 1]]
   }
  ],
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Boxed -> False
]
```

[image]

As you can see, this isn't quite perfect, because it doesn't follow the rounded edges of your textures, but extracting the shape of those and using it to generate a model on the fly will be a lot trickier.