# How to map rotate, pan, zoom to manipulate controls

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I am wondering if there is a way to restrict the motion of the rotate mouse cursor in when moving around a 3d plot.

For example, I want the y direction of the cursor to correspond to pulling the z axis toward or away from me (the camera), and the x direction to rotate the graphic around the z axis.

I can do something similar using,

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 0.05], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.2],
 {Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.1, 0, 0}}], Text["x", {1.2, 0, 0}], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.1, 0}}], Text["y", {0, 1.2, 0}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.1}}], Text["z", {0, 0, 1.2}]}},
 ViewVector -> {40 {Cos[a] Sin[b], Sin[a] Sin[b], Cos[b]}, {0, 0, 0}},
 ViewAngle -> 4 Degree ,
SphericalRegion -> True,
Boxed -> False
],
{{a, 0.3}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]},
{{b, 1.347}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}
]
```

where sliding $a$ rotates the graphic around the z axis (or rather the viewpoint) and sliding $b$ pulls the z axis in or out.

## Edit to make description clearer

The 3 dimensional ViewVector seems to be changed somehow by the 2 dimensional "double arrow Rotation" cursor when clicking and dragging on the plot.

I am not even sure how this is possible, but is it possible to restrict it so that only 2 of the 3 Euler angles (e.g. rotation about the z axis and inclination of the x-y plane) are changed?

The third Euler angle is natively controlled by the "additional rotation" cursor, which is available when you put the cursor in the corner.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. You want to make the usual rotating mouse gestures do zooming and other camera stuff?

Comment: It is hard to describe. Did you try the manipulate example above? What I would like is to map the vertical motion of the mouse when clicked and dragged to $b$ and the horizontal motion when clicked and dragged to $a$.

Comment: ShaunH, clear description. I haven't got it fresh in my head how `ViewVector` changes when you drag, and I don't have time now, and probably you do have it more clear, so I'll just suggest an idea. You can set `ViewVector->Dynamic[{blabla}, ({a, b}=sth[#])&]`, to make it change as you wish. You can also use an event handler with `MouseDragged` or `MouseClicked` event

Comment: @Rojo, I don't have a clear idea how `ViewVector` changes when you drag either!

Comment: @ShaunH have you read [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3528/17)?

Comment: @Silvia thanks for that link, the presentation was pretty cool too. But it still doesn't answer my question. The "double arrow Rotation" cursor seems to use the x y coordinate of the cursor to change the 3 coordinate `ViewVector`. How does this work?

Comment: @ShaunH Yes, it's possible to restrict it.  The pieces you need to get this working: 1. `Dynamic` works inside of `ViewVector` and `ViewPoint`. Search for those names [here](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php) for details.  2. It's possible to intercept changes to a variable through `Dynamic` through the second argument of `Dynamic`: please see the example in the Applications section [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locator.html) for a *very simple* example.  To do the same for your application, it'd take a bit more work and 3D maths. Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

OP has said:

> For example, I want the y direction of the cursor to correspond to pulling the z axis toward or away from me (the camera), and the x direction to rotate the graphic around the z axis.

I don't know in which version it was introduced but `"RotationControl" -> "Globe"` does exactly what you are asking for.

```
Graphics3D[Cuboid[], Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}]
```

> [image]

This is not the answer to the general question about the 3rd Euler angle etc. Unfortunatelly  I don't have time to play with this now.

If someone has time, here is my answer which shows how to play with mouse related events over `Graphics3D`:

[Changing the Actions in EventHandler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28881/5478)