# Changing the Actions in EventHandler

Tags: dynamic, graphics3d, eventhandler

I would like to be able to change which action specified events take depending on some condition. For example, I have established a `SetterBar`

```
SetterBar[Dynamic[setter], {Zoom, Pan}]
```

and created a graphic that I would like the left mouse button to cause to either zoom or pan, depending on what the value of `setter` is when the event occurs.

```
DynamicModule[{frac = 0, zoomval = 7*Pi/36, drag = {0, 0}, 
pt = CurrentValue[ImageSize], CurrentPosition = {1/2, 1/2}, 
panvalue = {0, 0}}, 
EventHandler[
Dynamic[Show[graphics, 
ViewCenter -> {{1/2, 1/2, 
   1/2}, {x = CurrentPosition[[1]] + panvalue[[1]], 
   y = CurrentPosition[[2]] - panvalue[[2]]}}, 
ViewAngle -> (Which[drag[[2]] > 0, 
   zoomval = Min[Pi*0.7, zoomval + frac*(Pi - zoomval)], 
   drag[[2]] < 0, 
   zoomval = Max[zoomval - frac*(Pi - zoomval), 0.2], 
   drag[[2]] == 0, zoomval = zoomval]), 
RotationAction -> "Clip"]], {{"MouseDown", 
 1} :> (a = CurrentValue[MousePosition]), {"MouseDragged", 
 1} :> {Which[
  setter == Zoom, {b = CurrentValue[MousePosition], drag = b - a, 
   frac = 0.5 Norm[drag]/Norm[pt]}, 
  setter == Pan, {b = CurrentValue[MousePosition], drag = b - a, 
   panvalue = {drag[[1]]/(pt[[1]]), 
     drag[[2]]/(pt[[2]])}}]}, {"MouseUp", 1} :> {frac = 0, 
 drag = {0, 0}, panvalue = {0, 0}, CurrentPosition[[1]] = x, 
 CurrentPosition[[2]] = y}}]]
```

This may be a little difficult to follow, but esentially I want the `Which` function to alter the action taken by the event `"MouseDragged"` depending on if setter is set to Zoom or Pan. Currently, everything works when the value is set to Zoom, but no action occurs upon setting the value to Pan.

Also, `graphics` is simply a red cylinder created for example.

```
graphics = Graphics3D[{Red, Cylinder[]}];
```

Comment: Manipulate[] can give you very similar functionality much more directly.  Do you have some specific need to use "MouseDragged" or similar events?  Also, best to show the minimum amount of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry I showed so much, just wasn't sure what was wrong exactly. I don't really have to specifically use event handler, but I would ideally be able to rely only on the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

As your code doesn't appear to run and presents so much to decipher before anyone could usefully help you with it, consider this simpler alternative:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Red, Cylinder[]}, 
   ImageSize -> iSize, 
   ViewAngle -> vAngle \[Degree]], {{iSize, 250}, 50, 500, 25}, {{vAngle, 40}, 50, 10, 1}]
```

A couple of screen shots of the output follows:

[image]

The `Manipulate` simply enables one to dynamically change the `ImageSize` of the `Graphics3D` object and its `ViewAngle`.  I've set an initial value of the variable for `ImageSize` to 250 and range it from 50 to 500 in steps of 25.

For `ViewAngle`, I've specified it in degrees, set a default as 40 and allow it to range from 50 to 10 with a step of 1.

Take a look at [howto/RotateZoomAndPanGraphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/RotateZoomAndPanGraphics.html)

Note that Mathematica typically enables 3D graphic output for rotating.  You may have to do a bit more thinking to incorporate Pan.

This approach may not do everything you want, but it may give you a different and simpler way to think about what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It's a nice alternative and I think I can make pan work. However, this is for a display and I would prefer to not have to rely so much on sliders. Any alternatives you can think of? @Jagra

Comment: Check out `Manipulate`'s options. It lets you use almost any type of control.  Good luck.

Comment: You helped a lot, and I managed to make something that I'm fairly content with. Do `Manipulate` and `EventHandler` not particularly play well together? @Jagra

Answer (score 2):

Here is the minimal example what you are probably looking for.

Switching between zooming and rotating is handled in two places:
`If` stops zooming unless `zoom==True`. `PassEventsDown->!zoom` prevents rotating when zooming is enabled.

```
DynamicModule[{y = .5, zoom},
 EventHandler[
              Column[{
                      Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic@zoom], "zoom"}],
                      Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 1, 
                      ViewAngle -> Dynamic@y, ImageSize -> 400]
                    }]
              ,
       "MouseDown" :> If[zoom, init = y + Last@MousePosition["Graphics"]],
       "MouseDragged" :> If[zoom, y = Clip[init-Last@MousePosition["Graphics"], {.2, 1}]],
       PassEventsDown -> ! Dynamic@zoom
             ]
       , Initialization :> (zoom = False)
            ]
```

> [image]

Comment: +1 for most elegant solution within the OPs original idea.  Also, very useful approach.  Thx

Comment: @Jagra your comment is far more rewarding than 3700rep :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using @Jagra's suggestion I was able to make a `Manipulate` function that was FAR neater than what I previously had (again, apologies for the unnecessarily long and  messy code).

```
Manipulate[
Graphics3D[{Red, Cylinder[]}, ViewAngle -> Dynamic[vAngle \[Degree]],
ViewCenter -> {{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, Dynamic[cen]}], {{vAngle, 30, 
"Zoom"}, 90, 10, 1}, {{cen, {1/2, 1/2}, "Pan"}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}]
```

While this isn't exactly what I was going for, I think it's definitely something that I can work with, and maybe tweak a little.

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't work. Not certain what you intend for `Pan`?  Not certain you need an additional 'Dynamic' inside of the `Manipulate`.  Maybe best to move this to the original post rather than as an answer.

Comment: @Jagra What does the code do for you? I updated it, and it currently allows me to use the Zoom slider to change the angle of view and the two-dimensional Pan slider to change the location of the center of view. I originally tried without the additional `Dynamic` inside of `Manipulate` and the code only worked until I rotated the Graphic or used the traditional `Shift` and `Ctrl` methods to Zoom and Pan. Now that I have put the `Dynamic` inside, the code continuously works for me.

Comment: Ah!  Much better.  Works great.  Looks good.  Congratulations.