# How to synchronize the display of dynamic objects?

Tags: dynamic, graphics3d

I was looking at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80007/constant-orientation-of-graphics-in-graphics3d), which asks to keep the orientation of some 3D graphics objects constant (relative to the viewer) while rotating the rest with the mouse.  I thought that maybe the coordinates can be given in terms of the `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical`, which do keep unchanged relative to the viewer.  I came up with this:

```
DynamicModule[{vv = {0, 0, 1}, vp = {1.3`, -2.4`, 2.`}}, 
 Graphics3D[{
   Cuboid[], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, Dynamic[vv]}]
   (*,Line[{{0,0,0}, Dynamic@vp}]*)
  }, 
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
  ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], 
  Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True]
 ]
```

The problem is that the updating of the `Line` and the rotation of the graphics are not synchronized.  The former happens with a short delay after the latter, leading to some flickering while rotating the graphics with the mouse.

How can we lock together *just the display* of the `Line` and the rest of the graphics, to avoid this flickering?

Answer (score 4):

Specifying an explicit `PlotRange` and moving the `Dynamic` outside the list in `Graphics3D` seems to create a smoother experience:

```
DynamicModule[{vv = {0, 0, 1}, vp = {1.3`, -2.4`, 2.`}}, 
  Graphics3D[
    Dynamic[{Cuboid[], Line[{{0, 0, 0}, vv}]}],
    ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
    ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv],
    Boxed -> False, 
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
]
```

Comment: It is enough if the `Dynamic` is moved to wrap the `Line`, no need to make the full content dynamical as well. I assume, `SpehericalRegion` cannot pre-determine the full region because of the dynamical content and that is why the explicit plot range is required.

Comment: Moving the `Dynamic` outside does indeed work.  I really wonder why this makes such a difference.