# How can I get this Graphics3D to rotate around a particular point?

Tags: graphics3d, animation, astronomy

I made this `Graphics3D` of the Sun with the plotted orbits of a few astronomical objects.

```
otherCelestials = AstronomicalData["MinorPlanet"][[;; 10]];
Graphics3D[{
  {Yellow, Sphere[AstronomicalData["Sun", "Position"], 0.05]},
  AstronomicalData[#, "OrbitPath"] & /@ otherCelestials
  }, Axes -> True, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

I would like it to rotate around the sphere representing the sun's position though. At the moment the `ViewCenter` is somewhere next to the sun, which means that when you rotate the plot, it rotates around that point and not the sun. How can I make it so that it rotates around the sun?

(The obvious thing to do would be set the `ViewCenter` of the plot to the coordinates of the sun, but in this case the sun's coordinates are given as `{0, 0, 0}`, but that just makes the `ViewCenter` point to the corner of the graph.)

Comment: Yes I did, and I also just tried `ViewCenter -> {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}}` to see whether that would make a difference, but neither of them did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please tell me if this meets your needs, I feel it does:

```
Graphics3D[{{
   Yellow, Sphere[QuantityMagnitude @ AstronomicalData["Sun", "Position"], 0.05]},
   AstronomicalData[#, "OrbitPath"] & /@ otherCelestials
 },
  Axes -> True, SphericalRegion -> True,  ViewVector -> {{1, -2, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}
]
```

[image]

---

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{{
   Yellow, Sphere[QuantityMagnitude @ AstronomicalData["Sun", "Position"], 0.05]}, 
  Thick,  AstronomicalData[#, "OrbitPath"] & /@ otherCelestials
  }, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewVector -> Dynamic[{2.5 {Cos@t, Sin@t, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, None],  
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewAngle -> 1, BaseStyle -> 18]
 ,
 {t, 0, 2 Pi, .1}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Kuba this actually does exactly what I was looking for. It's just very confusing when `ViewPoint` uses scaled coordinates and `ViewVector` uses ordinary coordinates... Btw for some reason this doesn't actually work for another `Graphics3D` that I'm working on but that's a matter for another question

Comment: @Aron Yes, I didn't realised it either when you first asked about `ViewCenter` etc. So thank you, now I'm aware of the difference :) Maybe you can describe shortly your setup here, I mean this one where this solution does not work.

Comment: Well in short, I have a very similar, albeit more elaborate setup with planets and their orbits around the sun, with sliders that control the zoom and rotation around the sun. For some reason though, although the rotation works and even seems to be focused on the sun, it seems to follow a highly elliptical orbit around the sun. Since I am using the exact same parametric function to control the `ViewVector` I don't know why it is behaving differently

Comment: @Aron Is `ViewAngle` fixed?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed at 35 degrees. Since I'm new here, would the best practice be to edit my question and add this other problem in with it, or is it better to create a new question for this?

Comment: @Aron better add a new one. this topic is consistent and finished :)