# Converting ViewPoint and ViewCenter to ViewVector

Tags: graphics3d, options, conversion

In the documentation about [ViewPoint](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/ViewPoint.html) in the section "Properties & Relations" we can read:
[image]

> "Convert ViewPoint to ViewVector by multiplying the length and
> pointing the center:"

But the images are not exactly same, the first is bigger than second at first glance.

So is it a bug or do they themselves do not know how to convert  ViewPoint and ViewCenter to ViewVector?

The code from the documentation page:

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Cuboid[]}, ViewPoint -> {3, -3, 3}]
Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Cuboid[]}, 
 ViewVector -> {2 {3, -3, 3}, {0, 0, 0}}]
```

Comment: I think the difference is only in the ``ImageSize``. Check with ``AbsoluteOptions`` (in V13), and you will see that in the second case, the ``ImageSize`` is slightly different. If you make it the same in both cases, you will get identical images: ``Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Cuboid[]}, ViewVector -> {2 {3, -3, 3}, {0, 0, 0}}, ImageSize -> {360, 360}]; Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Cuboid[]}, ViewPoint -> {3, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {360, 360}];``

Comment: No, they are not same, they may look like same, but try to rasterize both and compare image data. They are not equal.

Comment: Ah, well, you are partly right. I was displaying them in a row, ``Row[{Graphics3D[...], Graphics3D[]}]``, in which case they _are_ the same. Displayed separately, they are indeed not. Still, it looks like there is something about the margins/paddings, because they are not fundamentaly different (perspective-wise), only rescaled.

Comment: We are using mathematical tool not artistic. I want exact matching pixel by pixel. What is the exact mathematical formula for relation between `Viewpoint`, `ViewCentrer` and `ViewVector`? What they claim about their relation in the documentation is incorrect. If it was correct the images must have been the same regarding comparing their image data.

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicates: **([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46266/280))**, **([2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3528/280))**.

Comment: The two links discus only how it all should be - same as the documentation - "it should be this way", but in reality it is different. The code of second answer in second link do not even work anymore - When I run the code I got two images of completely  different perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have already suspected in the comments, there does not seem to be a problem in the formula for conversion between `ViewPoint` and `ViewVector` because the output images are only scaled versions of one another, and the difference is only in the outer padding.

The problematic option seems to be `SphericalRegion`, which is set to `Automatic` by default. Apparently, using `ViewPoint` turns `SphericalRegion` to `False`, making the output graphics be cropped to the top and bottom edge.

Let's first omit specifying `SphericalRegion`. To make the output images of same size, `ImageSize` has to be set manually.

```
Quit[];
ClearSystemCache[];

$Version
(* "12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)" *)

a = Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Cuboid[]}, ViewVector -> {2 {3, -3, 3}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, 300}];
b = Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Cuboid[]}, ViewPoint -> {3, -3, 3}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, 300}];

imga = Rasterize@a;
imgb = Rasterize@b;

GraphicsRow[{ImageAdjust[imga + imgb], ImageAdjust[imga - imgb]}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Different]

Now specify `SphericalRegion -> True`.

```
Quit[];
ClearSystemCache[];

c = Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Cuboid[]}, ViewVector -> {2 {3, -3, 3}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True];
d = Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Cuboid[]}, ViewPoint -> {3, -3, 3}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True];

imgc = Rasterize@c;
imgd = Rasterize@d;

GraphicsRow[{ImageAdjust[imgc + imgd], ImageAdjust[imgc - imgd]}, ImageSize -> 300]

MinMax[imgc - imgd]
(* {-0.501961, 0.376471} *)
```

[image: Same]

Both results now match. Although they are indeed not pixel-perfectly matching, I would consider this to be the solution for your problem. The remaining differences are probably – in my opinion – due to small numerical "errors" in the underlying linear algebra for graphics (when using either `ViewPoint` or `ViewVector`), and subsequent rasterization.

Note: I get the very similar results also in `"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`.

Comment: But this just means that when `ViewPoint` and `ViewCenter` are used the algorithm to render output is different than algorithm used with `ViewVector`. If the algorithm was the same and inputs given with same precision there can not be any differences (the conversion between the two is just one multiplication and sometimes even without it when box width is `1`). Then it has no much sense to explain how to convert between those two parameters if they do not state that it is just approximation - the more it is mathematical tool.

Comment: I accept your answer but not because it would solve my problem. I consider it to be a bug and so there could not be any better answer.