# How to correctly specify the ViewCenter here?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

The folowing code produces 2 graphicses:

- LEFT ONE (denoted `slika1`): camera view and an object (octahedron)
- RIGHT ONE (denoted `slika2`): rendered image of an object, given the coresponding view options

The center of view (denoted `ViewC`) (ABSOLUTE COORDINATES) is controled vith the first row of sliders.
The next three sliders control the displacement of camera from the center of view (denoted by `ΔT`).

In the code, the position of camera is denoted by `T`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
\[Epsilon]=.000001;

(*
-TčjiKota je: {krak1, vrh, krak2}
-obr je obroba
-FaktZamikaKot: premakne napis v smeri navzven kota za ta faktor*VelNap
*)
PlotajKot3D[TčjiKota_,Rkota_,Bnot_,Bobr_,DebObr_,Npodkotov_,NapTex_,VelNap_,FaktZamikaKot_]:=(
    (*
    SetOptions[MaTeX,"Preamble"->{
    "\\usepackage{color,bm}",
    "\\definecolor{Bobr}{rgb}"<>ToString[Bobr[[;; 3]]]
    }];
    *)
    VektKota1=TčjiKota[[1]]-TčjiKota[[2]];
    VektKota2=TčjiKota[[3]]-TčjiKota[[2]];
    kot=VectorAngle[VektKota1,VektKota2];
    RMjikota=Table[RotationMatrix[\[Theta]kota,{VektKota1,VektKota2}],{\[Theta]kota,0,kot,kot/Npodkotov}];
    LokKota=(TčjiKota[[2]]+Rkota # . Normalize[VektKota1])&/@RMjikota;
    
    DaljiceLoka=Partition[LokKota,2,1];
    TrikotnikiKota={
        DaljiceLoka[[;;,1]],
        Table[TčjiKota[[2]],Npodkotov],
        DaljiceLoka[[;;,2]]
    }\[Transpose];
        
    Show[
        Graphics3D[{RGBColor[Bnot],EdgeForm[],Polygon@#}]&/@TrikotnikiKota,
        Graphics3D[{RGBColor[Bobr],Thickness->DebObr,Line@LokKota}](*,
        
        Graphics3D[Text[
            MaTeX["\\color{Bobr}"<>NapTex,
            FontSize->VelNap],
            TčjiKota[[2]]+(Rkota-FaktZamikaKot VelNap) Normalize[Normalize@VektKota1+Normalize@VektKota2]
        ]]*)
        
    ]
);

oktaeder=Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor@{0,1,1,.5},EdgeForm[],
    Polygon[{
    {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}},
    {{-1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}},
    {{1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,1}},
    {{-1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,1}},
    {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,-1}},
    {{-1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,-1}},
    {{1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,-1}},
    {{-1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,-1}}
    }]
}];

res={resx,resy}=Round[{1920,1080}/2.7];




GEkrana[ViewC_,T_,d_,a_,\[CurlyPhi]_]:=(
\[CapitalDelta]T={x,y,z}=T-ViewC;  (*relativni T, glede na ViewCenter*)
xy=Sqrt[x^2+y^2];(*POZOR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*)
b=resy/resx a;
S=ViewC+(Norm[\[CapitalDelta]T]-d)Normalize@\[CapitalDelta]T;


\[CapitalDelta]x1=(b z x)/(2Norm[\[CapitalDelta]T]xy);
\[CapitalDelta]y1=(b z y)/(2Norm[\[CapitalDelta]T]xy);
\[CapitalDelta]z1=(b xy)/(2Norm[\[CapitalDelta]T]);
\[CapitalDelta]x2=(a y)/(2xy);
\[CapitalDelta]y2=(a x)/(2xy);
O1=S+{\[CapitalDelta]x1,\[CapitalDelta]y1,-\[CapitalDelta]z1}+{\[CapitalDelta]x2,-\[CapitalDelta]y2,0};
O2=S+{\[CapitalDelta]x1,\[CapitalDelta]y1,-\[CapitalDelta]z1}-{\[CapitalDelta]x2,-\[CapitalDelta]y2,0};
O3=S-{\[CapitalDelta]x1,\[CapitalDelta]y1,-\[CapitalDelta]z1}-{\[CapitalDelta]x2,-\[CapitalDelta]y2,0};
O4=S-{\[CapitalDelta]x1,\[CapitalDelta]y1,-\[CapitalDelta]z1}+{\[CapitalDelta]x2,-\[CapitalDelta]y2,0};


rot=RotationMatrix[\[CurlyPhi],\[CapitalDelta]T];
O1=S+rot . (O1-S);
O2=S+rot . (O2-S);
O3=S+rot . (O3-S);
O4=S+rot . (O4-S);
Oji={O1,O2,O3,O4};

rViewSfere=Max[Norm[# - ViewC] & /@ {T, O1}];
ViewSfera=Sphere[ViewC, rViewSfere];

(*zdej pa še dobimo žarke na drug stran ViewSfere*)
TO1=O1-T;
lžarkov=2 rViewSfere Cos@VectorAngle[-\[CapitalDelta]T,TO1];
žarki={T,T+lžarkov Normalize[#-T]}&/@Oji;

PiramidaŽarkov=Polygon[{
    žarki[[;;,2]],
    RotateRight@žarki[[;;,2]],
    žarki[[;;,1]]
}\[Transpose]];

(*
    Graphics3D[Text["1",O1]],
    Graphics3D[Text["2",O2]],
    Graphics3D[Text["3",O3]],
    Graphics3D[Text["4",O4]],
*)










slika1=Show[
    Graphics3D[Point@ViewC],
    Graphics3D[{Green,Point[T]}],
    Graphics3D[Point[S]],
    Graphics3D[{White,Line[{T,ViewC}]}],
    Graphics3D[{Yellow,Line@žarki}],
    Graphics3D[{RGBColor@{1,1,0,.5},EdgeForm[{RGBColor@{1,1,0,.9},Thickness@.002}],Polygon@Oji}],
    Graphics3D[{Opacity@.00002,ViewSfera}],
    Graphics3D[{RGBColor@{1,1,0,.06},EdgeForm[],PiramidaŽarkov}],
    Graphics3D[{
        RGBColor[{1,0,0}],Arrowheads[.008],
        ViewVIzh=Mean@{O3,O4}; RViewV=.8; ViewV=RViewV Normalize[O4-O1];
        Arrow[Tube[{{0,0,0},ViewV}+Threaded[ViewVIzh,2], .012]]
    }],
    PlotajKot3D[
        {\[CapitalDelta]T,{0,0,0},-\[CapitalDelta]T+\[Epsilon] ViewV}+Threaded[ViewVIzh,2],
        RViewV,RGBColor@{1,0,0,.1},RGBColor@{0,0,0,0},.01,30,"",15,0],
    oktaeder,
    
    Boxed->False,Background->Black,Lighting->"Neutral",
    
    ViewPoint->{0, -2, .5},ViewVertical->{0, 0, 1},
    SphericalRegion->ViewSfera,
    ImageSize->{resy,resy}
];







slika2=Show[
    oktaeder,
    Boxed->False,Background->Black,Lighting->"Neutral",
    
    ViewPoint->T, ViewVector -> {Scaled@T, ViewC},
    ViewAngle->ArcTan[b/(2 d)],ViewVertical->ViewV,
    ImageSize->res
];

{slika1,slika2}
);












Manipulate[
GEkrana[ViewC,ViewC+r{Cos[\[Beta]]Cos[\[Alpha]],Cos[\[Beta]]Sin[\[Alpha]],Sin[\[Beta]]},d,2 d Tan[ViewA],\[CurlyPhi]],

Style["ViewCenter in absolute coordinates",15,Bold],
    {{ViewC,{0,0,0}},{-1,-1,-1},{1,1,1}},
Delimiter,
Style["\[CapitalDelta]Viewpoint",15,Bold],
    {{\[Alpha],.6},0,2\[Pi]},
    {{\[Beta],.2},-\[Pi]/2+\[Epsilon],\[Pi]/2-\[Epsilon]},
    {{r,5},\[Epsilon],10},
Delimiter,
Style["ViewAngle",15,Bold],
    {{d,2},\[Epsilon],10},
    {{ViewA,15°},\[Epsilon],\[Pi]/2-\[Epsilon]},
Delimiter,
Style["ViewVertical je poljuben 
\[RightVector]  iz rdeče polravnine",15,Bold],
    {{\[CurlyPhi],0},0,2\[Pi]},

ControlPlacement->Left
]
```

For `slika2`, I first tried the option `ViewCenter -> Scaled@ViewC`. The result was wrong. Then I read this post: [Am I missing the point of ViewCenter?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28085/am-i-missing-the-point-of-viewcenter). The answer in it advised `ViewVector -> {Scaled@T, ViewC}`. In my case this gives more accurate result, but it is still wrong.

For example: if I leave the `ViewC` at the oreign `{0,0,0}` and delete `ViewVector -> {Scaled@T, ViewC}` from the code, using the same parameters, I get different result, without `ViewVector -> {Scaled@T, ViewC}`, then with it. This is shown on the nex image.
[image]

Also you see on the left image, that the bottom vertex should be on the image. But if you look on the right image, the bottom vertex is not on the image.
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I later tried it also with `SphericalRegion` and that seems to be working at least in this case (can't be 100% sure if it always works), so I'll not close the question just jet.

To be exact, instead of `ViewVector -> {Scaled@T, ViewC}`, I used `SphericalRegion ->  Sphere[ViewC, Norm@\[CapitalDelta]T/Sqrt[((2 d)/Min@{a, b})^2 + 1]]`

[image].

This follows from similar triangles, where `a` and `b` are sides of the camera rectangle at distance `d` from the camera.
[image]

**EDIT**

Below is a more usefull version of the code. You can use the function `Camera`, where the arguments are:

- `grafikaMo`: 3D thing you want to display
- `resMo`: resolution of the image
- `ViewCMo`: point in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, that camera aims (in the center of image)
- `ViewPPolarneMo`: polar coorinates $\{\alpha,\beta,r\}$ of a vector from `ViewCMo` to the camera. To use cartesian coords, just delete first 2 lines from the deffinition and use `\[CapitalDelta]TMo` and `\[CapitalDelta]T` instead of `ViewPPolarneMo` and `ViewPPolarne`.
- `ViewAMo`: angle between central axis of camera and the right plane of cameras view.
- `ZasukMo`: tilt angle of camera around central axis of camera

```
Remove["Global`*"];
Camera[grafikaMo_,resMo_,ViewCMo_,ViewPPolarneMo_,ViewAMo_,ZasukMo_]:=Module[{
grafika=grafikaMo,res=resMo,ViewC=ViewCMo,ViewPPolarne=ViewPPolarneMo,ViewA=ViewAMo,Zasuk=ZasukMo,
\[Alpha],\[Beta],r,\[CapitalDelta]T,T,x,y,z,xy,a,b
(*za d=1*)
},
    {\[Alpha],\[Beta],r}=ViewPPolarne;
    \[CapitalDelta]T={x,y,z}=r{Cos[\[Beta]]Cos[\[Alpha]],Cos[\[Beta]]Sin[\[Alpha]],Sin[\[Beta]]};
    T=ViewC+\[CapitalDelta]T;
    xy=Sqrt[x^2+y^2];
    a=2 Tan[ViewA];   
    b=res[[2]]/res[[1]] a;
    
    Show[
        grafika, Boxed->False,Background->RGBColor[{0,0,0}],Lighting->"Neutral",
        
        ViewPoint->T,
        SphericalRegion->Sphere[ViewC,Norm@\[CapitalDelta]T/Sqrt[(2/Min@{a,b})^2+1]],
        ViewAngle->ArcTan[b/2],
        ViewVertical->-(b/Norm@\[CapitalDelta]T) RotationMatrix[Zasuk,\[CapitalDelta]T] . {(z x)/xy,(z y)/xy,-xy},
        ImageSize->res
    ]
];
```

And also an interactive example:

```
oktaeder=Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor@{0,1,1,.5},EdgeForm[],
    Polygon[{
    {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}},
    {{-1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}},
    {{1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,1}},
    {{-1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,1}},
    {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,-1}},
    {{-1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,-1}},
    {{1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,-1}},
    {{-1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,-1}}
    }]
}];

resolucija=Round[{1920,1080}/2.7];



\[Epsilon]=.0001;
Manipulate[
Camera[oktaeder,resolucija,ViewC,{\[Alpha],\[Beta],r},ViewA,\[CurlyPhi]],

Style["ViewCenter v absolutnih koordinatah",15,Bold],
    {{ViewC,{0,0,0}},{-1,-1,-1},{1,1,1}},
Delimiter,
Style["\[CapitalDelta]Viewpoint",15,Bold],
    {{\[Alpha],.6},0,2\[Pi]},
    {{\[Beta],.2},-\[Pi]/2+\[Epsilon],\[Pi]/2-\[Epsilon]},
    {{r,5},\[Epsilon],10},
Delimiter,
Style["ViewAngle",15,Bold],
    {{ViewA,15°},\[Epsilon],\[Pi]/2-\[Epsilon]},
Delimiter,
Style["ViewVertical je poljuben 
\[RightVector]  iz rdeče polravnine",15,Bold],
    {{\[CurlyPhi],0},0,2\[Pi]},

ControlPlacement->Left
]
```