# Switching among view points in a Manipulate expression

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, options, gui-construction

**Edit**: Some additional viewpoints were included to make it easier to test.
Here's code for an alternative function, the graph of which  is a bit less symmetric.
Feel free to use either code set:

```
f = ArcCoth; Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Abs[f[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4],

  MeshFunctions -> 
   Function @@@ {{{x, y, z}, Re[f[x + I y]]}, {{x, y, z}, 
      Im[f[x + I y]]}}, MeshStyle -> {Orange, Green}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]], {{vp, {5, 8, 4}, "viewpoint"}, {
   {5, 8, 4} -> "mathematicians' default",
   {1.3, -2.4, 2} -> "Mathematica's default",
   {0, -2, 0} -> "in front",
   {0, -2, 2} -> "in front and up",
   {0, -2, -2} -> "in front and down",
   {-2, -2, 0} -> "left-hand corner",
   {2, -2, 0} -> "right-hand corner",
   {0, 0, 2} -> "directly above",
   {0, -Infinity, 0} -> "xz from y at -\[Infinity]",
   {0, 0, Infinity} -> "xz from z at \[Infinity]"
   },
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

---

It's easy to place preset `ViewPoint`s in a `PopupMenu` in order to switch among them.
But if I manually rotate the graphics object, the program ceases to respond to changes in the `PopupMenu` selection.

Is there a way to have both functionalities?: (1) the `PopupMenu` and (2) manual rotation.

If the answer is no, is there at least a way to turn off manual rotation?

Below is a simplified version of the code.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp], 
 Control[{{vp, {5, 8, 4}, "viewpoint"}, {
    {5, 8, 4} -> "mathematicians' default",
    {1.3, -2.4, 2} -> "Mathematica's default",
    {0, -2, 0} -> "in front",
    {0, -2, 2} -> "in front and up",
    {0, -2, -2} -> "in front and down",
    {-2, -2, 0} -> "left-hand corner",
    {2, -2, 0} -> "right-hand corner",
    {0, 0, 2} -> "directly above",
    {0, -Infinity, 0} -> "xz from y at -\[Infinity]",
    {0, 0, Infinity} -> "xz from z at \[Infinity]"
    },
   ControlType -> PopupMenu}]]
```

[image: viewepoints]

Comment: Manual rotation can be switched off by `Deploy@Plot...`

Comment: @Kuba  Thanks. Works well.  Any way to get both to work simultaneously?

Comment: @Kuba.  In the more realistic version of the code, I found I had to use `Deployed -> True` as an option of Manipulate.

Comment: Yes, I have forgotten that we are dealing with `Manipulate` and this option is available.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to nicely simplify your code.

Comment: Glad to do that.  Long code hides the essentials.

Comment: Maybe You should remove `Dynamic` from the code so it can reproduce the issue :). I'm not sure what is Your main goal now. Meanwhile You can take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/5478). See You tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that have been alluded to by @Kuba and @amr.

The **first** is that `vp` needs to be wrapped in [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html).  This is because in the graphics output the *value* of `vp` is stored, not a reference to `vp` itself.  `Dynamic` takes care of this, since it has the attribute `HoldFirst`.  The further effect of wrapping `vp` in `Dynamic` has to do with how the front end implements `Dynamic` with `Graphics3D`.  It will update the values of the "visible" `Dynamic` parameters, such as view properties (`ViewPoint` etc.), when the graphics are rotated.  [**Edit**] Just beware that some activities can overwrite the setting `ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp`.  For instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click (or right click) on the graphic and select "Top View" from the popup menu.  Your `Manipulate` will no longer work.  The view point setting has been changed to `ViewPoint -> Top`, and there's no way to get it back to `vp` (except to reevaluate the `Manipulate`).

One way to avoid that is to swim into the deep end with [`ViewMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewMatrix.html), which will override `ViewPoint` so that `ViewPoint -> Top` would be ignored; see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/extract-values-for-viewmatrix-from-a-graphics3d/5764#5764).  With `ViewMatrix` you should probably also set [`ViewCenter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewCenter.html) to be a dynamic variable (start with `vc = {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}`.  This will allow changes due to panning (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-drag) to be reset.

You can also turn off aspects of interactively modifying graphics with `Dynamic` -- a sort of anti-dynamic use of `Dynamic`.  For instance, `ViewCenter -> Dynamic[vc, (vc = {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}) &]` prevents the value of `vc` being changed when trying to pan with the mouse.  Thus there is no panning because `vc` cannot be changed.  You can do something similar with `ViewAngle` to prevent zooming.

The **second** problem is rotating after setting `ViewPoint -> {0, -Infinity, 0}`, etc. -- that is, a view point infinitely far away.  The rotation methods for graphics work only for a finite distance.  The front end just reassigns the view point to be a default distance, which seems to be `2.`.

**Turning off manual rotation**

Rotation of 3D graphics can be turned off with `Method -> {"RotationControl" -> None}`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> vp, 
  Method -> {"RotationControl" -> None}], 
 Control[{{vp, {5, 8, 4}, ""},
  {{5, 8, 4} -> "xyz", {0, -Infinity, 0} -> "xz", {0, 0, Infinity} -> "xy"},
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}]]
```

**Side views that are not infinite**

Another approach worth considering is having side views, such that the distances of the view points are all the same.  This makes rotating the image pleasant.  So instead of `Infinity`, one can put `Norm@N@{5, 8, 4}`.  (Apparently the view point has to be a vector of numbers, not just numeric quantities -- at least it didn't work with the exact value `Norm@{5, 8, 4}`.)  I include a few other alternations as suggestions (things I like, for you to consider).

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp, 
  SphericalRegion -> True],
 {{vp, {5, 8, 4}, ""},
  {{5, 8, 4} -> "xyz", {0, -Norm@N@{5, 8, 4}, 0} -> "xz",
   {0, 0, Norm@N@{5, 8, 4}} -> "xy"},
  PopupMenu[#1, Flatten@#2, "manual"] &}]
```

Comment: Very nice explanation of Dynamic's effects in Manipulate. (I'm not sure I fully digested it but can tell it's on the right track.  I'm inclined to avoid infinite distance viewpoints. For aesthetic reasons alone.  That there are technical issues, reinforces my gut feelings.  In an edit, I included some standard "side views" in the PopupMenu.

Answer (score 5):

But the answer is yes, You need `Dynamic` inside `Plot3D`

```
Manipulate[
           Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
                  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4], 
                  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp], 
           Control[{{vp, {5, 8, 4},""}, {{5, 8, 4} -> "xyz", 
                                         {0, -Infinity, 0} -> "xz", 
                                         {0, 0, Infinity} -> "xy"},
                   ControlType -> PopupMenu}]]
```

I'm not sure why. It looks like `Manipulate` is creating connection between controller and `vp` only in one way. I might miss something, appreciate any comments.

Comment: It kind of works, but in the code I'm using it runs into other issues. E.g. the standard settings don't always look the same after manual viewpoint changes.

Comment: @DavidCarraher You mean other elements of ViewMatrix?

Comment: In the longer code, it may drastically shrink the size of the graphics.  Or it changes some aspect of the point of view.  I included some additional viewpoints to see if that might help such flaws to appear in the short code (but haven't checked yet myself).

Comment: @DavidCarraher I think `, SphericalRegion -> True` is what You are looking for :). Cooperating with fixed size: `, ImageSize -> {300, 300}`

Comment: I still get major distortions with manual rotation, perhaps because my full applet uses Show with Plot3D and Graphics3D  (For technical reasons I need to use both).  The applet I'm making is for about 60 students, many of whom would likely find manual rotation confusing. So I think I'll probably opt for pre-set viewpoints. Thanks for your help and reminding me about the great posting elsewhere on SE (and on Wolfram's web site) about the fundamentals of three dimensional viewing.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Maybe [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28602/5478) is what can help You?

Answer (score 2):

As Kuba says, you can wrap the `vp` in `Dynamic`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]],

 {{vp, {5, 8, 4}, ""},
  {{5, 8, 4} -> "xyz", {0, -Infinity, 0} -> "xz", {0, 0, Infinity} -> 
    "xy"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

This does what you need, but maybe because of the switching between the Infinity perspectives and regular perspectives, you will get issues with the `ViewAngle` if you zoom in/out. One quick fix for this is to disable zooming:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  ViewAngle -> Dynamic[9 Degree, None],
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]],

 {{vp, {5, 8, 4}, ""},
  {{5, 8, 4} -> "xyz", {0, -Infinity, 0} -> "xz", {0, 0, Infinity} -> 
    "xy"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

I know why the Dynamic works here but I'm not sure why it's required. My guess is manual adjustment of the graphics disables programmatic adjustment. Similar to when you re-evaluate a Graphics3D expression and the output figure has the same size/perspective even if it has different contents. Imagine you're fiddling with some sliders in a `Manipulate` and the figure keeps resetting to the original perspective even though you want to see things from your own angle. That'd be annoying.

$-$

As a general remark, putting `Dynamic` inside a Manipulate is not a redundancy, as you might think. For example, compare the following with and without the Dynamic:

```
Manipulate[Pause[2];
 Graphics[{(*Dynamic@*)color, Disk[]}],
 {color, ColorSlider}]
```

Also try removing the `None` in our ViewAngle setting to see that Mathematica tries to assign a value to the expression "9 Degree." This should give you an appreciation for how dynamic Dynamic really is.

Comment: Hi, take Your code with ` ViewAngle -> Dynamic[9 Degree, None],` set the last ViewPoint and try to rotate it manually. Is this behaviour planned?

Comment: The second block of code produces some weird effects! Manual rotation sends me plunging into the middle of the magnified graphics, as if I had shrunk down to the size of an ant and been drawn into the screen.  Then, when I select a pre-set viewpoint, it takes up about 1/4 the area that it did before.  I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: The ColorSlider example appears to produce the same effect in both cases, but the one with `Dynamic` is much more responsive.

Comment: @Kuba that zoom effect always happens when you drop out of an Infinity perspective, it's not related to the `Dynamic`. the lack of zoom does make rotating meaningless for that perspective though. i'm not quite sure how the whole thing would be properly fixed without adding more variables and stuff.  @DavidCarraher, yea, the version with Dynamic is faster because the Manipulate doesn't re-evaluate its body, so the `Pause` isn't run.