# Chart illustrating options that affect Graphics/Graphics3D objects

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, options

In *Mathematica* there is a seemingly never-ending list of parameters that affect the appearance of `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` objects: `ImageSize`, `ImageSizeRaw`, `ImagePadding`, `ImageMargins`, `PlotRange`, `PlotRangePadding`, `PlotRangeClipping`, `PlotRegion`, ...

I'm looking for a chart that illustrates as many of these parameters as possible in one place.

What I'm looking for is something in the same spirit as [this chart](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/images/boxdim.gif) illustrating similar terminology for CSS3:

[image]

Comment: Great question, I would love to see this :) If you are interested in other options, there is a great example for [ViewMatrix for graphics 3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/5478) by [Yu-Sung Chang](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/820/yu-sung-chang)

Comment: Good selection of parameters. All of them involve regions that can be illustrated graphically.  Some other candidates for graphical illustration: `Offset`, `Placed`, `Invisible`, `Alignment`, `Scaled`, `ImageScaled`...

Comment: @Anon Why did you delete your `Manipulate` answer? I think it is a very good way for new users to discover all the nuances of the options interactively!

Comment: @IstvánZachar I felt it was too simplistic. I upgraded it and undeleted. If I get time, I might put labels and add more options.

Comment: @Anon Simplicity is rather important: you should never underestimate the helplessness of a new user! :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I doubt you can find a chart for all options, but take a look at this:

[image]

[image]

For this and other insights two courses by Yu-Sung are a must (there are notebooks and videos there):

- [**Graphics Language Quick Start**](http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2012/resources.html)
- [**Visualization: Advanced 3D
  Graphics**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/gen422.html)

The above chart is from the 1st one. The one @Kuba links in the comment to your question is from the 2nd - I show image below:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Interactive illustration of the most fundamental properties:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Overlay[{
     Framed[Graphics[{
        LightYellow, 
        Rectangle[{-plotRangePadding - plotRange, -plotRangePadding - 
           plotRange}, {plotRangePadding + plotRange, 
          plotRangePadding + plotRange}],
        LightGreen, 
        Rectangle[{-plotRange, -plotRange}, {plotRange, plotRange}],
        LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]
        },
       Background -> LightBrown,
       ImageSize -> size,
       ImageMargins -> margins,
       ImagePadding -> padding,
       AspectRatio -> aspectRatio,
       PlotRange -> plotRange,
       PlotRangePadding -> plotRangePadding,
       Axes -> True,
       AxesStyle -> Directive[Orange, 12], Frame -> True
       ]],
     Framed[Graphics[
       {}, ImageSize -> size - 2 margins, ImageMargins -> margins, 
       AspectRatio -> aspectRatio
       ]]
     }, Alignment -> Center],
   SwatchLegend[{LightBrown, LightBrown, LightYellow, LightGreen, 
     LightBlue}, {"The outer light brown area signifies image \
margins.", "The inner light brown area signifies image padding.", 
     "The light yellow area is designated by PlotRangePadding.", 
     "The light green area is designated by PlotRange.", 
     "The blue square is drawn using Rectangle[{0,0},{2,2}]"}],
   Text["All attributes are applied symmetrically. E.g. the margins \
are the same on every side of the object."]
   }],
 {size, 400, 1000}, {padding, 80, 200}, {margins, 80, 
  200}, {aspectRatio, 1, 5}, {plotRange, 2, 10}, {plotRangePadding, 1,
   10}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: As it often happens in Mathematica SE, I found it difficult to pick one out of multiple superb answers...  Since I did not pick yours, I want to at least thank you for it: I learned a ton from it.