# Use separate options for different elements in Show

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a few plots of different type. plot1 has gridlines and the rest do not. I use the option Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}] when plotting plot1. When I use Show to combine the plots the gridlines fall infront of the crosses as well which is not what I want. How do I force the crosses to appear completely in front of the figure.

I.e. I want to use Show[plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4] with some kind of options that transforms my figure from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

where evidently some other (irrelevant) changes have been made.

Comment: Many of the style elements of plots are buried in the graphics directives.  You can post-process the individual plots, but it's often easier just to recompute the plots with the new styling.  You cannot change the styling as shown in the question by only using options passed to `Show`. Rules like `plot /. _AbsoluteThickness -> AbsoluteThickness[1]` have to be applied to the graphics and not as options to `Show`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's fine, but what I'm really interested in here, is getting the "X" to appear in front of the gridlines. The gridlines belong to one plot and the "X" to another

Comment: I see.  I was distracted from that due to the many differences between the before and after images.

Comment: Use `Epilog`: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, GridLines -> {{0}, {0}}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, GridLinesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@5, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style[x, 38], {0, 0}]}]`

Comment: Yes sorry @MichaelE2 it's a pretty poor question, I'll neaten it up shortly and answer myself when I figure it all out. Kuba that answered my question thank you

Comment: Kuba's answer worked for me yes.

Comment: @Öskå I will do that later :) p.s. I found [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31762/5478) but where GridLines are is not explicitly shown :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation `Epilog` is applied after `Axes` even with `Method->"AxesInFront"` (and it seems after `GridLines` too) so you can use it to set layers as you need:

```
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1},  GridLines -> {{0}, {0}}, Frame -> True,  Axes -> False, 
                      GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness@9],
                           PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@9, 
                              Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
                              Epilog -> {Text[Style["X", 38, Bold], {0, 0}]}, 
                          Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image]