# how to make a custom filling to be semitransparent

Tags: plotting

I have this plot:

[image]

However, I would like the grid lines to be visible. I have tried to set the filling with some `Opacity` by means of `FillingStyle`. But when used, the filling loss the color, and turns standard blue with the assigned `Opacity`.

[image]

Is there any way to make my original filling semitransparent?

Oh, I would like a solution without making a background (like in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/can-i-make-a-plot-with-gradient-filling?noredirect=1&lq=1) post), as posible.

As a minimal example:

```
 GraphicsRow[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]], Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Automatic, GridLines -> Automatic], 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]], Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5], GridLines -> Automatic]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Showing the code of what you have tried would be helpful.

Comment: The plot is part of a long calculation with no relevance here. I think that the question is quite general to be used with any plot.

Comment: btw, is the question about transparency of filling or seeing grid lines on top? Because for the latter there is [Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64331/5478)

Comment: I have edited the question adding a minimal example. @Kuba I would like to see the grid lines on top. However, is not this equivalent to set an opacity to the filling?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas no it is not, changing opacity is only one way to do this. Other is to plot grid lines on top of plot. So is `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]], 
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Automatic, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]` the answer?

Comment: @Kuba, perfect. Your suggestion using `Method`works. That is a nice alternative to take it into account next time. Anyway, it would be interesting an answer working with the filling opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]],
  Filling -> Axis, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, {Opacity[0.5], Hue[y]}], 
 Filling -> Axis, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]