# Orthographic view (top,bottom,left,right,rear,front) and Isometric view using ViewMatrix

Tags: graphics3d

I want to know how to obtain the orthographic view (top,bottom,left,right,rear,front) and Isometric view using ViewMatrix.

I read the ViewMatrix documentantion but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Extract values for ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5764/17).