# How to show orthogonal views for a 3D plot

Tags: plotting

How to show orthogonal views for a 3D plot(ParametricPlot3D)?

Please refer to the following picture(top view/front view/side view):

[image]

Comment: Duplicate?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86557/isometric-perspective-for-graphics3d -- Also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84910, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample object:

```
g=Graphics3D[{Cylinder[],Blue,Cuboid[{-2,-3,-1},{2,3,0}]},Boxed->False]
```

[image]

There are special commands for this:

```
Show[g,ViewPoint->#]&/@{Back,Bottom,Front,Top,Left,Right}
```

[image]

The usefulness of all projections (**Left** different from **Right** etc.) is more clear on a completely asymmetric case:

```
m=ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{-1,1},{30,3}]];
Show[m,ViewPoint->#]&/@{Back,Bottom,Front,Top,Left,Right}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not quite an orthographic projection though. One needs to add `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`, which I also just learned myself by first setting something like `ViewPoint -> {Infinity, 0, 0}`, then using `Options` to see what options the resulting `Graphcis3D` _actually_ contains. (By that time I already wrote the first part of my answer, this is why I ended up mentioning `ViewProjection` only at the end.)

Answer (score 4):

What Vitaliy shows is not *quite* the full solution. Notice that in the `Front` view, the top of the cylinder still looks curved. With a true orthographic projection, it should look flat, as in the illustration given in the question.

To achieve an accurate orthographic projection, we need to set the view distance to infinity. Using Vitaliy's graphics (`g`) for illustration, this is what we get with `Front`:

```
Show[g, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

The view distance is not infinite, causing a noticeable curve on the cylinder cap.  Now let us set it to infinity:

```
Show[g, ViewPoint -> {Infinity, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

This is now a true orthographic projection.

This is documented in the doc page of [`ViewPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewPoint.html), under "Details".

Here's an isometric view:

```
Show[g, ViewPoint -> {Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image]

All good so far, but what if we want to view the object under a different angle, and still use orthographic projection? We can't use `ViewPoint -> {2 Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}` as `2 Infinity` is clearly the same as `Infinity`.

The solution is to use finite numbers in `ViewPoint`, but set `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`. See [`ViewProjection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewProjection.html).

```
Show[g, ViewPoint -> {2, 1, 1}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]