# How to replicate drawing applications' Quad-View playing with MatrixView?

Tags: graphics3d, options

I'm having trouble in figure out how to set the ViewMatrix in order to replicate the Quad-View that is available in drawing applications such as Blender.

In these packages, if I drag the point of view (rotating anf translating it), which never change the scene objects, and ask for a top view, for example, I see an object aligned with the screen axes - which is what I want.

[image: View] [image: Top View]

However, all tentatives with ViewMatrix produces a top view that is rotated. why?

How can I solve this, and replicate the Quad-View behavior?

By the way, it's very difficult to grasp from the documentation and this forum, what should be the "t" and "p" matrices in order to produce a FRONT, BACK, TOP, BOTTOM, RIGHT, LEFT and ISOMETRIC views.

Can anybody, please, explicitly write them? Many people will appreciate.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528)?

Comment: Do you want to set the `ViewMatrix` explicitly or are you simply after the correct view? `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` are somewhat more intuitive to use...

Comment: I want to set up ViewMatrix correctly.I think this is a point that Mathematica documentation could be improved. This is so common, and not so obvious, that should be stated explicitly.