# Changing the Rotate behavior of a 3D graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, output, rotation, user-interface

Is it possible to change the way Mathematica rotate its 3D output graphics, when the user uses the mouse ?  Here's a MWE to work with :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[p], Sin[p], 0},
    {p, 0, 2 Pi},
    Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> True,
    Ticks -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    ImageSize -> {700, 700},
    SphericalRegion -> True
]
```

By default, Mma rotates the view around a vertical axis when the user move the mouse from left to right and back.  I would like to make it rotate the view around the main axis ("z") in this example, instead.

If the user move the mouse vertically, then the view should rotate as usual (around the horizontal axis), or maybe around one of the axis of the plot ? ("X" or "Y", I don't know yet what would be best in this case).

---

**EDIT :**  When you use **Show** to plot several objects (surfaces, vectors, etc), Mathematica rotates the view around the "center of mass" of the whole.  In some cases, you may want to rotate your view around a particular point in space (the center of the main object, say).  So what command could achieve this ?

I tried **ViewCenter -> {{0, 0, 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}**, and also **ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}**, to rotate the view around the point **{0, 0, 1}** (for example), but it doesn't behave correctly.  When I move my mouse, I'm getting some weird motion with much exagerated view angles.

So what to do in this case ?

Comment: You're asking a new question! That's bad form! (-1).  See http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-to-avoid-and-what-to-do-with-ops-moving-the-goalposts-in-the-comments

Answer (score 9):

See "Method" in [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html).

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> True, Ticks -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, 
  Method -> {"RotationControl" -> Dynamic@rotate}],
 {rotate, {"Globe", "ArcBall", "TrackBall"}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To change the setting in an existing graphic, use `Show`:

```
g = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, Ticks -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, SphericalRegion -> True]

Show[g, Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}]
```

Comment: The command **Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}** appears to be doing exactly what I needed.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Cham You're welcome!

Comment: I'll wait a bit before marking your answer as "THE" answer, just in case someone post something else interesting.  This **"Globe"** method make the manipulations MUCH more easy !  In my view, it should be the default setting !

Comment: It is the default for `Plot3D`: `Plot3D[x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}] // Options`.  I guess the idea is that in such a plot the third axis is naturally vertical, but in a parametric plot, there is not always a natural orientation.

Comment: It make sense !  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I now need another option to rotate a 3D graphics.  If you show multiple 3D elements (surface, vectors, etc), you may still want Mathematica to rotate the whole set around a particular point (the surface's center, for example).  Now, the vectors are preventing this, depending on their location in space.  How can we tell Mathematica to rotate the whole around a particular point ?

Comment: @Cham You can tweak `PlotRange`, `ViewCenter`, `ViewVector`, and/or `ViewMatrix`.  See for example, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/extract-values-for-viewmatrix-from-a-graphics3d