# How to get the desired view in ViewPoint function

Tags: graphics

What should be the values for ViewPoint function to show the position I want?

My code is this:

```
Clear[x, y, z];

Association @@ Solve[x + 2 y - z == 8, z];

eqplano = %[z];

ponto1 = {x, y, z} /. Solve[{x + 2 y - z == 8, y == 1 - x, z == 3 + 2 x}, {x, y, z}];

ponto2 = {x, y, z} /. Solve[{x == 0, y == 1 - x, z == 3 + 2 x}, {x, y, z}];

linha = Transpose[{x = {-10, 10}, y = 1 - x, z = 3 + 2 x}];

Clear[x, y, z];

plano = Plot3D[eqplano, {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red], 
     Style["y", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red], Style["z", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red]}];

sol = Show[{plano, 
   Graphics3D[{Green, Thickness[.005], Line[linha], Red, PointSize[0.04], 
     Point[ponto1], Point[ponto2]}]}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

The values were applied manually, because I do not understand how to get the values by calculation:

Here my intention was to get a view parallel to the plane and observe the line upright:

```
Show[sol,ViewPoint->{-2.75,5.21,.48}]
```

Here my intention was to get a view where the plane is in position horizontal and have a view perpendicular to the line:

```
Show[sol,ViewPoint->{-2.28, -2.28, -.875}]
```

If someone may make an explanation about ViewPoint function would be of great help.

Comment: Take a look at `ViewVector` + `ViewVertical`, here is a nice diagram: [ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/5478)

Comment: If you put the code in one line, `%` is error prone.

Comment: I formatted your code but I may have also changed things with respect to Kuba's comment above in doing so.  Note the caveat in any case.

Comment: What is the difference between "view parallel to the plane" and "view where the plane is in position horizontal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plane, line and points are:

```
eqplano = x + 2 y - 8;
linha = Module[
  {
   x = {-10, 10},
   y,
   z
   },
  Transpose[{x, y = 1 - x, z = 3 + 2 x}]
  ];
ponto1 = {x,y,z} /. Solve[{x + 2 y - z == 8, y == 1 - x, z == 3 + 2 x}, {x,y,z}];
ponto2 = {x,y,z} /. Solve[{x == 0, y == 1 - x, z == 3 + 2 x}, {x,y,z}];
```

The calculations that cause the plane to appear horizontal or the line to appear vertical depend upon the ratios of the bounding box of the 3D plot (i.e., `BoxRatios`).

It will be easiest to start with ratios that match the axes length.

### BoxRatios -> Automatic

The `plano` plot is changed so that the `PlotRange` is set and the `BoxRatios` match the `PlotRange` (i.e., {2, 1, 4}.

```
plano = Plot3D[
  eqplano,
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 5}, {-13, 7}},
  BoxRatios -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5],
  AxesLabel -> {
    Style["x", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red],
    Style["y", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red],
    Style["z", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red]
    }
  ]
```

**Computation**

Here are two vectors in the plane, one showing the change in `z` with a unit change in `x`, the other showing a change in `z` with a unit change in `y`. Any linear combination of these two vectors is a line parallel to the plane.

```
vecx0 = {1, 0, 1};
vecy0 = {0, 1, 2};
```

Using these vectors here are two lines from the center in the directions of `vecx0` and `vecy0`.

```
center = {0, 0, eqplano /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}};
lineX = {center, center + 5 vecx0};
lineY = {center, center + 5 vecy0/2};
```

`sol` is a plot of the plane, line and points with the two vectors added.

```
sol = Show[
  {
   plano,
   Graphics3D[
    {
     Green,
     Thickness[.005],
     Line[linha],
     Red,
     PointSize[0.04],
     Point[ponto1],
     Point[ponto2],
     Arrowheads[0.03],
     Black,
     Arrow[lineX],
     Blue,
     Arrow[lineY]
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any linear combination of `xvec0` and `yvec0` as the viewpoint will show the plane collapsed to a line.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[sol,
    ViewPoint -> xfac*vecx0 + yfac*vecy0
    ],
   xfac*vecx0 + yfac*vecy0
   }],
 {{xfac, 5}, -10, 10},
 {{yfac, 5}, -10, 10}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order for the plane to appear to be horizontal for every step in the `xvec0` direction the viewpoint must be set to two steps in the `yvec0` direction.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[sol,
    ViewPoint -> facH*vecx0 + 2 facH*vecy0
    ],
   facH*vecx0 + 2 facH*vecy0
   }],
 {{facH, 5}, -10, 10}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order for the line to appear vertical for every step in the `xvec0` direction the viewpoint must be set to one negative step in the `yvec0` direction.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[sol,
    ViewPoint -> facV*vecx0 - facV*vecy0
    ],
   facV*vecx0 - facV*vecy0
   }],
 {{facV, 5}, -10, 10}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### AspectRatio -> 1

The original plot had the `AspectRatio` set to one.

```
planoO = Plot3D[
  eqplano,
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 5}, {-13, 7}},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5],
  AxesLabel -> {
    Style["x", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red],
    Style["y", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red],
    Style["z", FontSize -> 20, Bold, Red]
    }
  ]

solO = Show[
  {
   planoO,
   Graphics3D[
    {
     Green,
     Thickness[.005],
     Line[linha],
     Red,
     PointSize[0.04],
     Point[ponto1],
     Point[ponto2],
     Arrowheads[0.03],
     Black,
     Arrow[lineX],
     Blue,
     Arrow[lineY]
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
```

With the `AspectRatio` set to one, the `BoxRatios` are {1, 1, 0.4}. Now the calculations are similar but need to be adjusted by the change in the length shown on the screen.

```
ratio = {1, 1, 0.4}/{2, 1, 4};
```

Here is the plot where the plane appears to be horizontal. For every two steps in the `xvec0` direction the viewpoint must be set to one step in the `yvec0` direction and then multiplied by the ratio.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[solO,
    ViewPoint -> (2 facH*vecx0 + facH*vecy0)*ratio
    ],
   (2 facH*vecx0 + facH*vecy0)*ratio
   }],
 {{facH, 5}, -10, 10}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order for the line to appear vertical for every step in the `xvec0` direction the viewpoint must be set to one negative step in the `yvec0` direction and then multiplied by the ratio.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[solO,
    ViewPoint -> (facV*vecx0 - facV*vecy0)*ratio
    ],
   (facV*vecx0 - facV*vecy0)*ratio // N
   }],
 {{facV, 5}, -10, 10}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

There is an infinite number of view directions perpendicular to a give line.  You must be able to specify the Viewpoint directions *uniquely*.

One alternate way is to make an interactive Viewpoint selector:

```
sol = Manipulate[
  Show[{plano, 
    Graphics3D[{Green, Thickness[.005], Line[linha], Red, 
      PointSize[0.04], Point[ponto1], Point[ponto2]}]},
   ViewPoint -> {a, b, c},
   ImageSize -> 500],
  {a, -5, 5},
  {b, -5, 5},
  {c, -5, 5}]
```

And read off the desired Viewpoint values.