# How can it be that ViewPoint and ViewVertical are not perpendicular?

Tags: graphics3d, rotation

Execute the following code, then manually copy the outputted plot and use it in the next code:

```
Plot3D[{0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 2}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}]
```

Next code:

```
(* here paste the plot of previus output*)// Options;
ViewPoint . ViewVertical /. %
```

Execute it and the output should be zero or something very small like `-1.11022*10^-16`.
Then rotate the plot with mouse and execute once again. The output should be again zero.

So far so good - vectors defined by `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` are perpendicular so their product is zero.

Now use this code instead of the first one:

```
Plot3D[{0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 2}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, 
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "ArcBall"}]
```

Do the same as before with a new plot.
First output (without rotation) is zero as expected. But once you rotate it the dot product is no more zero.

Why? What `Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "ArcBall"}]` has to do with it?

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125081/53172) we can see a 3D scene from which it is evident that the two vectors should be always perpendicular.

Comment: I would only expect `ViewVertical` and `ViewVector` to be orthogonal

Comment: As long as `ViewCenter={0,0,0}` `ViewPoint` and `ViewVector` are identical. In both cases we have `ViewCenter` at origin.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 gives zero in both examples!

Comment: So it seems as a bug.