# How to get IOS "tossing feature" in Wolfram IOS Player to work in Mathematica

Tags: graphics

I would like to get the tossing feature in the IOS app to work in the Mathematica pc version.  See the video below at the 8:50 mark to see the tossing feature in IOS.  Is this possible on a pc?  Is it possible with touchscreen pc?  How would I go about enabling this feature programmatically in Mathematica 11?

Please see the video below at the 8:50 mark.

[Wolfram Player for IOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yCqZWaMgxE)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's not built-in in desktop.

If you want to roll this yourself you can (but it gets a bit gross).

Here's the prototype code I've been working with, based on, in a sense, computing an angular momentum for the [`ViewMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewMatrix.html).

```
Clear[tossableGraphic];
Options[tossableGraphic] =
  Join[
   Options[Graphics3D],
   Options[DynamicWrapper]
   ];
tossableGraphic[g_, showView : True | False : False, 
  ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {
   viewPoint = OptionValue[ViewPoint],
   viewAngle = OptionValue[ViewAngle],
   viewVertical = OptionValue[ViewVertical],
   viewCenter = OptionValue[ViewCenter],
   viewMatOld,
   timeStart = None,
   timeEnd = None,
   momTime,
   momTimeNew,
   viewMom,
   calcMom,
   setViewMat,
   resetMom,
   movedFlag
   },
  If[showView,
    Column[{
       #,
       ViewPoint -> Dynamic[viewPoint],
       ViewAngle -> Dynamic[viewAngle],
       ViewVertical -> Dynamic[viewVertical],
       ViewCenter -> Dynamic[viewCenter]
       }] &,
    Identity
    ]@
   DynamicWrapper[
    EventHandler[
     Graphics3D[
      g,
      FilterRules[
       {
        ViewPoint -> Dynamic[viewPoint],
        ViewAngle -> Dynamic[viewAngle],
        ViewVertical -> Dynamic[viewVertical],
        ViewCenter -> Dynamic[viewCenter],
        ops
        },
       Options[Graphics3D]
       ]
      ],
     {
      "MouseDown" :>
       (
        timeStart = Now;
        resetMom[];
        setViewMat[]
        ),
      "MouseDragged" :>
       (
        resetMom[];
        If[! ListQ@viewMatOld[[1]],
         viewMatOld[[1]] =
          Replace[viewPoint, Except[_List] -> {0, 0, 0}]
         ];
        If[! ListQ@viewMatOld[[3]],
         viewMatOld[[3]] =
          Replace[viewVertical, Except[_List] -> {0, 0, 0}]
         ];
        movedFlag = True
        ),
      "MouseUp" :>
       (
        timeEnd = Now;
        calcMom[]
        ),
      PassEventsDown -> True
      }
     ],
    If[! DateObjectQ@momTime, momTime = Now];
    momTimeNew = Now;
    With[{
      tDiff =
       QuantityMagnitude[
        UnitConvert[momTimeNew - momTime, "Seconds"]
        ]
      },
     If[viewPoint =!= Automatic,
      Replace[viewMom[[1]],
       {ts_, vecs_} :>

        With[{r = RotationMatrix[ts*tDiff, vecs]},
         If[MatchQ[r, {__List}],
          viewPoint = r.viewPoint
          ]
         ]
       ]
      ];
     If[viewVertical =!= Automatic,
      Replace[viewMom[[3]],
       {ts_, vecs_} :>

        With[{r = RotationMatrix[ts*tDiff, vecs]},
         If[MatchQ[r, {__List}],
          viewVertical = r.viewVertical
          ]
         ]
       ]
      ]
     ];
    momTime = Now,
    Evaluate@FilterRules[
      {
       TrackedSymbols :> {viewMom},
       ops,
       UpdateInterval -> .1
       },
      Options[DynamicWrapper]
      ]
    ],
  Initialization :>
   {
    resetMom[] :=

     viewMom = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
    resetMom[],
    setViewMat[] :=
     viewMatOld =
      {
       viewPoint,
       viewAngle,
       viewVertical,
       viewCenter
       },
    setViewMat[],
    calcMom[] :=
     (
      If[movedFlag &&

        AllTrue[{timeStart, timeEnd}, DateObjectQ],
       viewMom =
        Replace[viewMom, Automatic -> {0, 0, 0}, 1];
       With[{ts = 
          QuantityMagnitude@
           UnitConvert[timeEnd - timeStart, "Seconds"]},
        viewMom[[1]] =
         {
          1/ts,
          {
           Replace[viewMatOld[[1]], Automatic -> {0, 0, 0}],
           viewPoint
           }
          };
        viewMom[[3]] =
         {
          1/ts,
          {
           Replace[viewMatOld[[3]], Automatic -> {0, 0, 0}],
           viewVertical
           }
          }
        ];
       Replace[viewMom, Automatic -> {0, 0, 0}, 1]
       ];
      movedFlag = False;
      timeStart = None;
      timeEnd = None
      )
    }
  ]
```

It works if you swipe directly up:

```
tossableGraphic[{Sphere[], Sphere[{1, 0, 0}]}]
```

[image: asd]

But any other direction leads to funkiness:

[image: badbadbad]

To get this to work properly would require a complete understanding of the the [different components of the `ViewMatrix`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/38205) combine to give the view we see.

With that in hand, it would be possible to implement this, and would even be possible to introduce a damping like they show in that video.

Unfortunately I don't really want to get into the details of parsing the `ViewMatrix` bits right now, so consider this a template for an answer, not an answer itself.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain you should put in a suggestion or post the same question on Wolfram Community (WRI is generally more responsive there).

Comment: I will do that.

Comment: You should also like (on both) that this a cross-posting so that people know to look one place or the other. See some of Kuba's posts to get a sense for what I mean.