# viewpoint of 3d plot?

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to visualize a Convolutional Neural Network. Here is my code and figure:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Black,Opacity[1],Thickness[0.1]}],
            FaceForm[{Gray,Opacity[0.02]}],
    Cuboid[{1,11,8},{4,19,18}],
    Cuboid[{7,2,9},{10,22,30}],
    Cuboid[{7,7,13},{10,11,16}],
    Cuboid[{12,7,14},{15,17,25}],
    Cuboid[{12,12,16},{15,14,18}]},
    ViewPoint->{4, -4, 4}]
```

[image: a busy cat]

White what I prefer it this viewpoint. 
[image: prefer]

I have tried dynamically adjusting the viewpoint, however, the vanishing point for the 3d plot always seems too close. Could anyone kindly help?

Comment: The posted code does not generate the posted graphics. For one, `Thickness[0.1]` should have resulted in unreasonably thick edges. Have you tried much larger values for the `ViewPoint`, perhaps together with `ViewAngle -> All`?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/extract-values-for-viewmatrix-from-a-graphics3d/3538#3538  -- but it sounds like you want to pick larger values, e.g. `ViewPoint -> 20 {1, -1, 1}` or something bigger than `20`.  (Though to me, the picture showing your preference seems to have a closer vanishing point than your `Graphics3D`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
Graphics3D[
....,
ViewPoint->{a,b,c}],
{a,-1,1},{b,-1,1},{c,-1,1}]
```