# Extract ViewVertical from ViewMatrix

Tags: graphics3d, linear-algebra

Given a [`ViewMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewMatrix.html) setting of the form `{t, p}`, how can one determine the `ViewVertical`?

Let's say we have

```
vm = {
  {
    {0.10402567469787839`, 0.05634724046135078`, 0., 0.06671318616834762`}, 
    {-0.033304268882567746`, 0.061484804090894324`, 0.09542953968274223`, -0.10079092470343654`}, 
    {0.045451481623891156`, -0.08391042761333754`, 0.06992535634444795`, -0.030220722382910785`}, 
    {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`}
  }, 
  {{1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.5`}, {0.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.5`}, {0.`, 0.`, -1, -0.5`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`}}
};
```

The (normalized) `ViewPoint` can be found with

```
qr = QRDecomposition[vm[[1]]];

vpn = Sign[Diagonal[qr[[2, 1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]]]] qr[[1, 1 ;; 3, 3]]
```

> ```
> {0.384185, -0.709265, 0.591054}
> ```

```
Norm[{1.3, -2.4, 2}] * vpn
```

> ```
> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}
> ```

Can the `ViewVertical` be found in a similar fashion?

Comment: From Heike's formulae from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5764), one could use `EulerAngles[]` to recover rotation angles, but retrieving `ViewVertical` from those does not look immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Thanks, I went down that rabbit hole too. I should have added that in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check, and given the time since you asked, bounty and all, I'm assuming the obvious doesn't work, right? `Inverse[vm[[1]]].{0, 1, 0, 0} // Most` ?

Comment: No, I don't think it does.

Answer (score 1):

May be this code could be supportive

```
vm = {{{0.10402567469787839`, 0.05634724046135078`, 0., 
     0.06671318616834762`}, {-0.033304268882567746`, 
     0.061484804090894324`, 
     0.09542953968274223`, -0.10079092470343654`}, \
{0.045451481623891156`, -0.08391042761333754`, 
     0.06992535634444795`, -0.030220722382910785`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
     1.`}}, {{1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.5`}, {0.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.5`}, {0.`, 
     0.`, -1, -0.5`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`}}};
```

Let define some function

```
gvm = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[]}, ViewMatrix -> vm]
```

To get point we simply use

```
AbsoluteOptions[gvm, ViewPoint]

Out[]= {ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}}
```

We see that result exactly the same what you calculated. Now we can get vertical as follows

```
AbsoluteOptions[gvm, ViewVertical]

Out[]= {ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}}
```

Comment: It looks like `AbsoluteOptions` is just returning the default values. The same results are returned for the examples in the `ViewMatrix` reference page.

Comment: @ChipHurst So you think it is not `ViewVertical` as it suggested in `vm`?

Comment: In this case they agree, but for any `vm` this will always return `{0., 0., 1.}`.

Comment: @ChipHurst It looks like option `ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}` is default option for any `ViewMatrix->{t, p}`.