# view angles Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

I'd like to create a widget that allows you to specify one of two `ViewPoint`s.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   Cuboid[]
   },
  ViewPoint -> Which[a == 1, {0, 0, -2}, a == 2, {-2, 2, 2}]
  ],
 {a, {1, 2}}
 ]
```

After executing, you can pick between `a==1` or `a==2`, which will indeed change the point of view. But if you rotate the image with the mouse, this no longer works.

I'd like to allow rotation by the user (which should deselect buttons `1`  and `2` under `a`), but also be able to snap back to one of the two presets if the user then presses one of the `a` buttons again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest that the viewpoints be vectors of the same length.  Otherwise the perspective changes, which I found disorienting.  The fix is based on the fact that graphics parameters may be controlled in the front end via `Dynamic`.

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{Cuboid[]}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@a],
 {a, {N@{0, 0, -2 Sqrt[3]} -> 1, N@{-2, 2, 2} -> 2}}]
```

---

*Update incorporating my comment and response to @DavidG.Stork's comment:*

The above resets the `ViewPoint` correctly. It does not reset `ViewVertical` or `ViewAngle` or `ViewCenter` or any of the other parameters that go into the ViewMatrix that can be changed by manipulating the graphics with the mouse (in case I've omitted to mention one). It does not seem possible to interactively change `ViewRange`. See [Extract values for ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/extract-values-for-viewmatrix-from-a-graphics3d/3538#3538) for introduction to view parameters.

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{Cuboid[]},
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic@a[[1]],
  ViewVertical -> Dynamic@a[[2]],
  ViewAngle -> Dynamic@a[[3]],
  ViewCenter -> Dynamic@a[[4]]],
 {a, {
   N@{{0, 0, -2 Sqrt[3]}, {0, 0, 1}, Automatic, Automatic} -> 1, 
   N@{{-2, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 1}, Automatic, Automatic} -> 2}}
 ]
```

Comment: As far as I understand the OP, your code does solve his problem.  After I rotate the cube I click the "other" preset button... I get the proper view but the cube remains rotated.  I think the OP wants to reinitialize the view *AND* the orientation of the cube.

Comment: Ooops... does *not* solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No, it resets the ViewPoint correctly. It does not reset `ViewVertical` or `ViewAngle` or `ViewCenter` or any of the other parameters that go into the `ViewMatrix` that can be changed by manipulating the graphics with the mouse (in case I've omitted to mention one).  The above works exactly the way I interpreted the problem, but differently than you interpreted it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If you want a solution that solves your interpretation, then use something like `Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Cuboid[]}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@a[[1]], ViewVertical -> Dynamic@a[[2]]],  {a, {N@{{0, 0, -2 Sqrt[3]}, {0, 0, 1}} -> 1, N@{{-2, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 1}} -> 2}}]` -- you can add list elements and options for `ViewCenter` and `ViewAngle` if you want to reset pan/zoom actions by the user.

Comment: It all centers on what the OP means by "preset":  just the viewpoint, or the viewpoint plus the original configuration of the cube.  @rhomboidRhipper:  please weigh in!

Comment: The updated code above does all I could ever hope for. Thanks.