# Projection of curve 3D (x,y,z) on the x-y plane

Tags: plotting, graphics, equation-solving, graphics3d, image-processing

I have a following systeme :

\begin{equation}
\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    (\beta+\frac{1}{2}\delta^{2})\nu_{1}(u)-\delta\nu_{2}(u)+\nu_{3}(u)& = &0\\
   (\beta+\frac{1}{2}\delta^{2})\upsilon_{1}(u)-\delta\upsilon_{2}(u)+\upsilon_{3}(u)& < &0\\
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

where

\begin{align*}
&\nu_{1}(u)= q(u)f[q(u)],\\
&\nu_{2}(u)= f[q(u)]^2 + F(x)q(u)f[q(u)],\\
&\nu_{3}(u)= \left(u (f[q(u)])^2 + \frac{1}{2}u^2q(u)f[q(u)]\right),\\
&q[u] := Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], u], \ (the \ quantale \ at \  u)\\
&f[q(u)]=PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], q(u)] \ (the \ density \ at \ q(u)),
\end{align*}

and  for the inequality, $\upsilon_{i}(u)=\nu_{i}^\prime(u)$ with respect $q(u)$ for $ i\in \{1,2,3\}$ with $(\beta,\delta,u)\in [0.1]\times[0.1]\times[0.1]$.

I would like to look at the projection of this system of equation onto the plane  $(\beta,\delta)$ and $(u,\delta)$ in Mathematica or in r.

My code sets up the  full 3-d view of the 3D plot, which is not what I want. And I think there are some thing wrong in my picture. I'd like to see two of the views $(\beta,\delta)$ and $(u,\delta)$ on different figure.

```
q[u_] := Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], u]
f[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
h1[u_, a_, e_] := ((((a^2)/2 + e)*(-q[u])*(f[q[u]])) - 
a*(-q[u]*f[q[u]]*u  +   f[q[u]]^2) + 
u*f[q[u]]^2 - (u^2)/2*q[u]*f[q[u]])/(1/6 - a/2 + (a^2)/2 + e)
h2[u_, a_, e_] := (((a^2)/2 + e)*((q[u]^2) - 1)*f[q[u]]) - 
a*(u*(q[u]^2 - 1)*f[q[u]] - 3* q[u]*  f[q[u]]^2) + f[q[u]]^3 - 
2*u*q[u]*f[q[u]]^2 - 
u*q[u]*f[q[u]]^2 + ((u^2)/2)*(q[u]^2 - 1)*f[q[u]]
ContourPlot3D[ h1[u, a, e] == 0, 
{a, 0, 1}, {u, 0.1, 0.9}, {e, 0, 1.5}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{u, a, e}, h2[u, a, e] > 0]]
```

The graph 3D :
[image]

I want to try do verify if my plot 3D is true and if it is possible to have the projection on both plan $(\beta,\delta)$ and $(u,\delta)$.

Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Comment: As I understood, projections are solutions of an initial  system with one of coordinates is equal to zero. So, (Beta, Delta) view appears as when `u=0`. And it could be drawn in usual `ContourPlot`

Additionally, you can see projections at your 3D graph just using appropriate `ViewPoint`

Comment: No the projection is all the image of the curve on the surface (Beta, Delta) , for example if we consider a sphere x^2+y^2+z^2=0 this is the equation of the sphere, and the projection on (y,z)  is a circle. I want to do the same here.

Comment: Aha :) So, `ViewPoint` helps you to see it

Comment: Your expression contains a bracket mismatch. Could you please check?

Comment: It's done, I correct the code. Now, do you have some idea to help me to solve the problem

Comment: This takes ages to evaluate so it would be handy if you included a simple example. I think [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-make-a-drop-shadow-for-graphics3d-objects/1030#1030), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955692/shadows-in-mathematica-graphics3d) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32378/is-there-something-like-densityplot3d-to-visualize-atomic-orbitals/32441#32441) are heavily related if not duplicates

Answer (score 5):

This may serve as a starting point - extract all `Line`s from the 3D graphics and get rid of the third component in all coordinate triples (an old but useful trick):

```
plot = ContourPlot3D[
   h1[u, a, e] == 0, {a, 0, 1}, {u, 0.1, 0.9}, {e, 0, 1.5}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{u, a, e}, h2[u, a, e] > 0]];

Cases[plot[[1]] // Normal, _Line, 
   Infinity] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> {x,y} // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Damn you and your quick typing!

Comment: @gpap meet me at noon [here](http://typing-speed-test.aoeu.eu/) :D

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the best way to **draw** projections is select the resulting 3D-graphics and to choose viewpoint when styling menu appeared. For orthogonal projections it should be

`ViewPoint -> {0, \[Infinity], 0}
ViewPoint -> {\[Infinity], 0, 0}
ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
q[u_] := Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], u]
f[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
h1[u_, a_, 
  x_] := ((((a^2)/2 + x)*(-q[u])*(f[q[u]])) - 
    a*(-q[u]*f[q[u]]*u + f[q[u]]^2) + 
    u*f[q[u]]^2 - (u^2)/2*q[u]*f[q[u]])/(1/6 - a/2 + (a^2)/2 + x)
h2[u_, a_, x_] := (((a^2)/2 + x)*((q[u]^2) - 1)*f[q[u]]) - 
  a*(u*(q[u]^2 - 1)*f[q[u]] - 3*q[u]*f[q[u]]^2) + f[q[u]]^3 - 
  2*u*q[u]*f[q[u]]^2 - 
  u*q[u]*f[q[u]]^2 + ((u^2)/2)*(q[u]^2 - 1)*f[q[u]]
ContourPlot3D[h1[u, a, x] == 0, {a, 0, 1}, {u, 0.1, 0.9}, {x, 0, 1.5},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{u, a, x}, h2[u, a, x] > 0], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image: Graphics3D]

[image: Second perspective]

[`PerformanceGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html)  is a Mathematica built-in. It can be set to `Speed` and or `Quality`. `Speed` is the option of the trick to be fast.

The output looks brilliant and close to the long time calculation. I did it with V12.0.

```
Cases[%443[[1]] // Normal, _Line, 
   Infinity] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> {x, 
    y} // Graphics
```

[image: Graphics]

is already close to the other solution and a fast calculation too.

This runs in seconds than in hours.

The time-consuming parameter is `Mesh`. For `Mesh -> 10` the plane results take a two-minutes effort and:

[image: Grapics result with 10 mesh lines]

The PerformanceGoal compiles internally the distributions functions and uses only a polynomial interpolated approximation. That results in the speed up.