# How do you manipulate a line that starts at a fixed point and moves with another line?

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to create a simulation of a person(line) walking along a wall(plane) with a lamppost behind the person(fixed point) that casts a shadow along the wall while the person is moving. I'm having a hard time understanding how to do this. I've created the person and the wall within a manipulate function already, I just don't know how to create the "shadow".

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/938)?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
height = 1/2;
comps = {floor, wall1, wall2};
lamp = {0, 0, 1};
person[px_, py_, high_] := {px, py, high}
ray[t_, px_, py_, high_] := lamp (1 - t) + t person[px, py, high]
MapThread[(#1[t1_, t2_] := #2) &, {comps, {{t1, t2, 0}, {1, t1, t2}, {t1, 1, t2}}}];

lims = Outer[#1[t1, t2] /. 
       First@Solve[ray[t, px, py, #2] == #1[t1, t2], {t, t1, t2}] &, comps, {0, height}];

objDraw[obj_] := Polygon[#[[Last[FindShortestTour@#]]] &@(obj @@ # & /@ 
                                                                  Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2])]

scene = Graphics3D[{objDraw /@ comps, Yellow, Sphere[lamp, .05]}, 
                   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}];

Manipulate[Show[scene,
                Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.01], Black,
                Line[{person[Sequence @@ pos, 0],  person[Sequence @@ pos, height]}], 
                Gray,
                Quiet@Select[Line /@ (# /. Thread[{px, py} -> pos] & /@ lims), 
                             FreeQ[#, ComplexInfinity] &]}],
                Boxed -> False], 
          {pos, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 dd = Norm[d];
 Graphics3D[
  {PointSize[0.04], Yellow, Point[{d[[1]], d[[2]], h}],
   {Black, Thickness[0.02], Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]},
   {Gray, Thickness[0.02], 
    Line[{{0, 0, 0}, 
          {-(h/(h - 1) - 1) d[[1]], -(h/(h - 1) - 1) d[[2]], 0}}]}},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 3}}],
 {d, {-.5, -.5}, {.5, .5}},
 {h, 1.2, 3, ControlType -> VerticalSlider, ControlPlacement -> Left}]
```