# Adding positional guides to multiple points in 3D plots?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I have a graph showing multiple points in 3D space and need to accurately be able to represent their position. I'm looking to add dropping points underneath similar to this example graphic: [image] I could add shadows similar to : [How to make a drop-shadow for a Graphics3D objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-make-a-drop-shadow-for-a-graphics3d-objects) , but positional lines would give a clearer view.

I'm struggling to add the same effect to multiple points. My current image is:

```
pointstoplot = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 3}]

npoints = Range[10]

Show[Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], PointSize[0.04], Point[pointstoplot]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Text[npoints[[#]], pointstoplot[[#]]] & /@ npoints}], 
 Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1, AxesLabel -> {Column[{"x"}], Column[{"y"}], Column[{"z"}]}]
```

[image]

- Is this possible in Mathematica?
- The dropping points would
  ideally fall from the individual points to the plane of the x-axis
- Thankyou in advance

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange.  If you found @sumit's answer helpful (and I assume you did, since you accepted the answer) consider upvoting the answer as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can draw `Line`

```
Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], PointSize[0.04], Point[pointstoplot],
 Black, Dashed, PointSize[0.02], Gray, 
 Table[{Line[{p, {p[[1]], p[[2]], 0}}],
        Point[{p[[1]], p[[2]], 0}]}, {p, pointstoplot}]}]
```

[image]

`{p[[1]], p[[2]], 0}` defines that the lines end at `z=0` plane. You can also do the same thing to other planes as well.

Comment: Thankyou so much Sumit- The extra touch of the markers at the end of the lines will be even more helpful for viewers of the image

Answer (score 6):

```
SeedRandom[1]
pointstoplot = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 3}];
```

You can use [`ListPointPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html) with the option `Filling -> Axis`:

```
lpp = ListPointPlot3D[pointstoplot, BoxRatios -> 1, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.04], Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

labels = Graphics3D@MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #] &, pointstoplot];
Show[lpp , labels]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`BubbleChart3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart3D.html) with a custom `ChartElementFunction` to add the dashed lines:

```
cEF = Module[{m = Mean[Transpose[#]]}, {ChartElementData["Bubble3D"][##], 
     PointSize[Large], Point[{m[[1]], m[[2]], 0}], Thick, Dashed, 
     Line[{{m[[1]], m[[2]], 0}, m}]}] &;

BubbleChart3D[Append[#, 1] & /@ pointstoplot, 
 BubbleSizes -> {.05, .05}, 
 ChartLabels -> Range[Length@pointstoplot], LabelStyle -> Medium, 
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ChartElementFunction -> cEF, 
 FaceGrids -> {}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.04]]
```

[image]

To show the three drop lines you can modify `cEF` as follows:

```
cEF2 = Module[{m = Mean[Transpose[#]], bb = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"]}, 
   {ChartElementData["Bubble3D"][##], PointSize[Large], 
    {Point[#], Thick, Dashed, Line[{#, m}]} & /@ 
      (MapAt[#, m, {#2}] & @@@ 
        {{bb[[1, 1]] &, 1}, {bb[[2, 2]] &, 2}, {bb[[3, 1]] &, 3}})}] &;

BubbleChart3D[Append[#, 1] & /@ pointstoplot, 
 BubbleSizes -> {.05, .05}, ChartLabels -> Range[Length@pointstoplot],
 LabelStyle -> Medium, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF2, FaceGrids -> {}]
```

[image]